# Como funciona este if/else com "?" e ":"?

Tags: javascript, if

Estou estudando JavaScript e tenho dúvidas quanto às diferentes formas de se fazer um `if`/ `else`. Por exemplo, isto:

```
foo ? foo : foo
```

Como exatamente funciona?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Outras respostas já explicaram como funciona o [operador condicional ternário](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operador_Condicional), com bons exemplos. Ele avalia expressões condicionais, de maneira parecida com o `if`:

```
var variavel = condicao ? valorSeTrue : valorSeFalse;
```

Ou seja, se a condição (por exemplo `x > 5`) for verdadeira, a `variavel` recebe o valor `valorSeTrue`, e se for falsa, o valor `valorSeFalse`.

Uma diferença fundamental em relação ao `if` é que o ternário* é um operador, e não um *statement*. Ele sempre resulta em um valor, que é retornado, como se vê no exemplo. Não tem como inicializar uma variável em uma linha com `if` justamente porque ele não gera valor nenhum.

Por isso o operador condicional ternário costuma ser mais utilizado para atribuição de valor a uma variável, enquanto o `if` comum é mais usado para controle de fluxo.

A vantagem do ternário para atribuição de valor é clara: não é preciso repetir o nome da variável. Por exemplo, nesta atribuição com `if` usamos 6 linhas (incluindo a declaração da variável):

```
var x;
if(foo) {
    x = 10;
} else {
    x = 20;
}
```

Ou, na melhor das hipóteses, duas linhas:

```
var x = 20;
if(foo) x = 10;
```

Já com o operador pode-se declarar, aplicar a condicional e atribuir em uma única linha:

```
var x = foo ? 10 : 20;
```

O operador condicional ternário é recomendado para casos simples, pois condições complexas ou aninhadas podem dificultar a leitura do código:

```
var cargo = salario <= 1000 ? 'junior' : salario <= 5000 ? 'senior' : 'diretor';
```

Se as opções de valor a ser retornado (`valorSeTrue` e `valorSeFalse` no meu exemplo do início) forem chamadas de função, esse operador pode até ser utilizado para controle de fluxo:

```
// Cuidado: código abaixo pode ser péssima prática
// se você não souber o que está fazendo!
validaEmail(email) ? enviaEmail(email) : mostraErro();
```

Nesses casos há quem defenda o uso exclusivo desse operador em vez do `if`, especialmente quando se programa em estilo funcional (onde ainda se poderia capturar o retorno das funções `enviaEmail` ou `mostraErro`, caso necessário). Eu pessoalmente acho que cada um tem o seu lugar, e em geral prefiro usar o ternário para atribuições, e o `if` para controle de fluxo.

---

**(*)** O operador condicional ternário é popularmente conhecido simplesmente como "ternário", ou "operador ternário". Ele é ternário porque tem 3 argumentos (a condição e os dois possíveis valores), mas a qualidade de ser condicional pode ser vista como mais relevante, já que trata da sua função. Nesta resposta, optei por chamar algumas vezes só de "ternário", pela simplicidade, e outras pelo nome completo, pra reforçar.

Comment: +1 por referir que este operador retorna um valor (que pode ser atribuído a uma variavel, dentro de outro ternário ou num if statement.)

Comment: De uma certa forma é a melhor explicação, apesar de não dar exemplos úteis (até porque já foram dados). Tem gente que tem preconceito com operador ternário. É o típico caso do "li em algum lugar que **pode** ser menos legível e então vou abominar ele, até onde ele é o melhor caminho". Tem que entender o fundamento do recurso para usá-lo corretamente.

Comment: @bigown Tentei incluir exemplos que encaixassem aqui sem repetir as outras respostas. Acha que melhorou (está mais completo) ou piorou (mais confuso)?

Comment: Melhorou bem. Quer uma ideia? Não que ela seja tão necessária, mas em todas respostas faltam o contraponto. O exemplo de uso errado. Mas fica a seu critério se cabe na resposta ou se vale o esforço.

Comment: Eu nunca tinha entendido essas coisas, e graças à sua resposta eu consegui entender, belíssima resposta. +1

Answer (score 43):

O que você tem é um [**operador condicional ternário**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/be21c7hw%28v=vs.94%29.aspx), uma variante de if/else, muito comum não só em JavaScript.

> **A sintaxe é:** [ condição a testar ] **?** [ resposta se verdadeiro ] **:** [ resposta se não verdadeiro ]

Exatamente esse operador condicional ternário que você mostrou com `foo` três vezes não faz nada... mas se você tiver

```
var a = dog ? cat : mouse;
```

então se `dog` for verdadeiro (i.e, diferente de `0`, `false`, `null`, `undefined`) então `a` recebe o valor de `cat`, se for falso recebe o valor de `mouse`

Exemplo de condições:

```
var valor = 10;
valor == 20 ? 'sim' : 'não' // retorna 'não'
valor !=20 ? 'sim' : 'não' // retorna 'sim'
valor < 20 ? 'sim' : 'não' // retorna 'sim'
valor - 10 ? 'sim' : 'não' // retorna 'não' porque 0 é interpretado como false, neste caso melhor usar (valor - 10) == 0 ?
```

Este operador condicional ternário é o semelhante a

```
if(condição) { //faz algo se a condição for verdadeira }
else { //faz outra coisa caso contrário }
```

Porém (e crédito ao [@bfavareto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4916/129) por referir esse detalhe que tinha esquecido de referir), este operador retorna um valor (que pode ser atribuído a uma variavel, dentro de outro ternário ou como condição de um outro if statement).

Assim pode usar-se

```
var variavel = foo ? foo : bar;
// ou mesmo, ainda mais comprimido, útil em alguns casos
var variavel = foo || bar;
```

Answer (score 33):

## Visão Geral Sobre Condicionais no Javascript

O javascript é uma linguagem realmente interessante nesse aspecto.
Além de estruturas da linguagem para controle de fluxo **`if/else`**,
**`switch`** e outros, e também o operador ternário
**`condição ? a : b`** que alterna entre valores, existem ainda
usos inusitados de operadores lógicos, que podem atuar no lugar
de alguns testes ternários, especialmente o operador lógico OU
que nesse caso assume o nome de "operador de coalescência":
**`anulável || valor-padrão`**. Podemos ainda citar, formas de
fazer if sem usar if, que consta em usar um mapa associativo entre valores e
respostas, e não usar nenhum if nem switch.

### Estruturas de Controler de Fluxo

Vou citar apenas as estruturas de controle de fluxo de execução linear:
`if` e o `switch`.

**if**

O `if` é uma estrutura de controle de fluxo baseado em uma condição,
que sempre possui um statement/bloco de execução para quando a
condição é verdadeira, e pode opcionalmente apresentar um statement/bloco
para quando for falsa.

```
if (condicao) verdadeiro();
else falso();
```

Sintaxe segundo a [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else#Syntax):

> if (condition)
>          statement1
>   [else
>          statement2]

**switch**

Já o `switch` é uma estrutura de controle de fluxo que permite desviar
a execução para um dentre vários pontos, dependendo do valor de uma expressão.
Cada ponto de desvio é marcado com um rótulo `case valor:`, ou então o
rótulo padrão, que é executado quando nenhum outro é igual à expressão.

Suponhamos uma expressão variável, que pode assumir os valores: "pequeno",
"médio" e "grande", ou outros valores quaisquer.

```
switch (expressao) {

    case "pequeno":
        pequeno();
        break;

    case "médio":
        medio();
        break;

    case "grande":
        grande();
        break;

    default: // não é pequeno, nem médio, nem grande
        tamanhoInvalido();
        break;
}
```

Note que é usada a palavra-chave `break`, que serve para sair do bloco
do switch ao final de cada trecho. Isso é feito, pois o javascript
continuaria executando o trecho do rótulo seguinte na auxência do
`break`.

Sintaxe do switch na [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch#Syntax)

Um switch com `break`s ao final de cada trecho, equivale a `if`s em cadeia.
O código anterior poderia ser escrito assim:

```
if (expressao == "pequeno") {
    pequeno();
}
else if (expressao == "médio") {
    medio();
}
else if (expressao == "grande") {
    grande();
}
else {
    tamanhoInvalido();
}
```

### Operadores condicionais

O operador condicional ternário, é o mais conhecido, mas à medida que
se vê códigos em javascript, se encontra ocasionalmente o operador
de coalescência.

O operador ternário escolhe um entre dois valores, baseando-se em uma condição.

```
var mensagem = sexo == 'M' ? "bem vindo senhor" : "bem vinda senhora";
```

Já o operador de colescência, serve para indicar um valor padrão, caso uma
expressão seja avaliada como falsa. O seu uso é feito, quando uma variável
pode possuir o valor anulado:

```
var opcaoDoUsuario = usuario.opcao || "Opção padrão";
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rvMRS/)

Isso equivale ao seguinte:

```
var opcaoDoUsuario = usuario.opcao ? usuario.opcao : "Opção padrão";
```

Note que essa é uma forma de definir um valor padrão para quando o
valor da variável é nulo por exemplo, pois nulo é avaliado como falso.

**Outras loucuras com operadores**

```
a && metodo();
```

equivale a

```
if (a) metodo();
```

Essa forma bizarra de fazer um if, mesmo parecendo inútil,
encontra um uso razoável na **minificação de arquivos de script**.
Em arquivos minificados, essa técnica economiza 2 caracteres.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GB77M/) ← esse fiddle não está rodando sozinho, portanto aperte Run que vai funcionar!

### Usando arrays e mapas associativos no lugar de ifs

Usar arrays e mapas associativos no lugar de ifs, é uma boa prática
que pode tornar o programa mais fácil de ententer, principalmente
quando se nota que há muitas estruturas de if/switch se repetindo pelo
código a fora.

```
// suponha que 'pequeno', 'medio' e 'grande' são funções
var mapaDeTamanhos = { "pequeno": pequeno, "médio": medio, "grande": grande };
```

Agora no lugar dos switchs, podemos fazer assim:

```
// suponha que tamanho é uma variável que só pode assumir os valores
// "pequeno", "médio" e "grande"
mapaDeTamanhos[tamanho]();
```

Obviamente que não se deve fazer isso com todos os ifs/switchs, mas sim
quando isso de fato tornar o programa mais fácil de entender... usar nomes
descritivos também ajuda.

Note ainda que essa técnica dificulta indicar um padrão,
tal como o `deafult` do `switch`. Poderiamos fazer como a seguir, mas ai
a legibilidade vai ficar um pouco abalada (o que é péssimo):

```
// que ver isso vai pensar: "mas que droga é essa?"
// e vai ficar com cara de WTF =\
(mapaDeTamanhos[tamanho] || tamanhoInvalido)();
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BAUA9/)

Comment: sua resposta é bem mais do que a pergunta; Não acha melhor criar uma pergunta e respondê-la, e por essa resposta aqui?

Comment: @EmersonRochaLuiz A pergunta também não foi muito específica.

Answer (score 17):

Essa forma de if-else é conhecida como operador condicional ternário.
É comum em várias linguagens, não só para javascript.

A vantagem desse formato é que você faz um if-else em uma linha e forma bem limpa.

O formato é:

> < condição > **?** < caso verdadeiro > **:** < caso falso >**;**

**Exemplo:**
Se eu utilizar um operador condicional ternário para limitar o valor `x` para sempre ser no mínimo `40`, seria:

```
x = (input < 40) ? 40 : input;
```

Agora compare com:

```
if (input < 40)
    x = 40;
else
    x = input;
```

Answer (score 15):

Isso é um operador ternário. [Veja documentação oficial na MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Embora possa complicar a legibilidade de código, em algumas situações é extremamente útil e sucinta.

Exemplo:

```
// Pseudo código
condicao ? executa-se-verdadeira : executa-se-falsa

// Imprime "1 não é maior que 2"
console.log(1 > 2 ? "1 é maior que 2": "1 não é maior que 2");
```

**Recomendações úteis**

- Não é obrigatório, embora possa melhorar legibilidade, uso de parenteses. Mas sim apenas `?:`
- Útil quando condição, situação verdadeira e situação se falsa cabem em uma linha, do contrário `if-else` tradicional funciona
- Aninhar mais uma condição ternária não é recomendada na maioria das linguagens

Answer (score 10):

## Ternários, binários e unários

Ternário, do latim *ternarius*, quer dizer "composto de três itens". As operações ternárias, sejam em matemática ou em ciência da computação, **são aquelas que têm três operandos**.

Disso, pode-se inferir que existem operações **unárias, binárias e ternárias** também.

[image: exemplo de operação binária]

Acima, um exemplo de operação binária. É composta por dois operandos, `X` e `Y`, e resulta em um só valor.

## O operador condicional do JavaScript

> O operador condicional (ternário) é o único operador JavaScript que possui três operandos. Este operador é frequentemente usado como um atalho para a instrução if. [Fonte.](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operador_Condicional)

O JavaScript possui um único operador ternário, que é o operador condicional. É frequentemente chamado de operador ternário, por ser o único da linguagem. Ele não é **O** operador ternário, porém **UM** operador ternário.

```
resultado = {condição} ? {expressão se verdadeiro} : {expressão se falso}
```

Portanto, sobre o operador condicional do JavaScript, o `?:`, como muitas das respostas já exemplificaram:

```
idade >= 18 ? servirVinho() : servirSuco()
```

Lê-se: se `idade` é maior ou igual à `18`, então `servirVinho()`, caso contrário, `servirSuco()`.

## Outros operadores ternários em outras linguagens

Mas não pense que operações ternárias se limitam ao `?:`. Em alguns dialetos do SQL existe o `BETWEEN`, que é um operador ternário:

```
[...] WHERE {campo} BETWEEN {expressão 1} AND {expressão 2}
```

Veja que é um ternário pois faz uma operação composta de três itens e as evalua em um só, que no caso é verdadeiro ou falso.

## Operações unárias no JavaScript

O JavaScript, como a maioria das linguagens *C-like*, tem esses operadores unários. Recebem um operando, `X`, e resultam em um só `Y`.

```
i++ // incremento
i-- // decremento
-i  // negativo
+i  // positivo
!i  // negação
```

Comment: +1 depois do edit, é uma boa explicação do termo, agora que virou um complemento usando terminologia correta..

Answer (score -3):

```js
var a = 10;

//Método padrão 

if(a == 10){
  //Faça isso
}else{
  //Faça isso
}

//Método simplificado

a == 10 ? /*Faça isso*/ : /*Faça isso*/
```

Comment: Não há nada de errado em responder perguntas antigas ou já respondidas, mas só faz sentido fazê-lo se for adicionar informações novas ou apresentar de forma diferente das já apresentadas. Não acredito ser o caso, então se você acha que sua resposta realmente ajuda de uma forma que as outras não, recomendo você editá-la e deixar mais clara possível, explicando com texto a ideia que deseja passar, não apenas código.