# Problema com Jquery UI Slide Left

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Eu estou a desenvolver um projecto e precisava de saber como dar slide numa `div` para a esquerda. De momento estou a usar:

```
$('#idDiv').toggle('slide', { direction: 'left', distance: 450 });
```

Eu queria que a minha `div` de `500px` de width deslizasse e deixasse `50px` à mostra. O problema é que quando ela acaba de dar o slide de `450px` ela desaparece. Eu sei que o `toggle` tem a ver com o `hide` e `show`, mas será que existe outra maneira (sem usar o `animate` para dar resize) de dar slide para a esquerda sem que esta desapareça?

Está aqui um [exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/WUhX7/2/) do que disse.

Answer (score 3):

O método [**`.toggle()`**](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) faz a `div` aparecer/desaparecer, é melhor usar o método [**`.animate()`**](https://api.jquery.com/animate/) e animar a `margin-left` por exemplo. A largura (`width`) poderia também ser uma alternativa.

Assim para poder fechar e voltar a abrir podes usar uma *flag*. Uma flag é uma variável útil para saber o estado do elemento.

Neste caso uso-o para guardar informação sobre se está aberto ou fechado. Esta flag no primeiro exemplo é uma variável global, no segundo exemplo está guardada dentro de um campo `data` do próprio elemento.

Assim a cada clique ele vai verificar com [**um operador ternário**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4908/129) se a flag `open` tem o valor `true` ou `false` e consoante isso retornar `"-250px"` (caso `open` for `true`) ou `"0px"` (caso `open` for `false`):

```
var open = true;
$(document).click(function () {
  $("#toggle").animate({
    'margin-left': open ? "-250px" : "0px"
  }, 500);
  open = !open;  // mudar a flag para o oposto do que estava usando o operador de negação "!"
});
```

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/B5sZ6/1/)

---

Outra alternative é ter um campo data no elemento que guarda esta flag sobre estar aberto ou não:

HTML

```
<div id="toggle" data-open="true"></div>
```

JS

```
$(document).click(function () {
  var elemento = $("#toggle");
  elemento.animate({
    'margin-left': elemento.data('open') ? "-250px" : "0px"
  }, 500);

  // mudar a flag para o oposto do que estava usando o operador de negação "!"
  elemento.data('open', !elemento.data('open')); 
});
```

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/B5sZ6/3/)

---

#### O terceiro exemplo (e talvez melhor) é usando uma classe e transições CSS:

CSS

```
    #toggle {
        width: 300px;
        height:300px;
        background: #ccc;
        -webkit-transition: margin-left 500ms ease;
        -moz-transition: margin-left 500ms ease;
        -ms-transition: margin-left 500ms ease;
        -o-transition: margin-left 500ms ease;
        transition: margin-left 500ms ease;
    }
    .toggle {
        margin-left: -250px
    }
```

JS

```
    $(document).click(function() {
        var $toggle = $("#toggle");
        if ($toggle.hasClass('toggle')) $toggle.removeClass('toggle');
        else $toggle.addClass('toggle');
    });
```

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/B5sZ6/8/)

Comment: Obrigado, acho vou utilizar esta dica e vou usar um if para voltar a dar a margin inicial

Comment: @blackblather, juntei exemplo para voltar a abrir também

Comment: O unico problema é que eu nao precebo muito dessa maneira que usaste para solucionar o problema e como eu tenho que defender o meu projecto, posso ter o azar de me perguntarem sobre isso e depois nao sei explicar como deve de ser, da outra maneira estou mais à vontade caso perguntem algo. Mas de qualquer maneira obrigado :)

Comment: @blackblather, juntei explicação e mais um exemplo / variante

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação, é sempre bom aprender coisas novas :)

Comment: @blackblather, acrescentei mais uma variante :P

Comment: @Zuul obrigado :)

Answer (score 1):

Eu nao estou muito dentro de jQuery e preciso de explicar o codigo quando for fazer a apresentação do meu projecto (PAP) e a maneira que arranjei de solucionar o problema foi:

```
$(" #sideBarE ").click(function(e)
        {
            var divE = $('#empresas');
            var marginE = divE.css('margin-left');
            //alert(marginE);
            if (marginE == "0px")
                $('#empresas').animate({'margin-left':"-400px"}, 1000);
            else
                $('#empresas').animate({'margin-left':"0px"}, 1000);
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
```

Comment: Ao utilizares o método [`.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) estás a impedir a propagação e consequente aviso do que acabou de acontecer no elemento com o identificador `sideBarE` para os seus elementos pais. Digo isto porque não sei se realmente precisas desse método ai. (uma vez que referes que vais ter que explicar o código, avalia a necessidade do uso deste método) ;)

Comment: Eu sei, era esse o objectivo visto que eu tenho mais 2 divs, cada uma delas com efeitos diferentes, se eu tirar esse método, isto fica uma salganhada ahahah

Answer (score 0):

Tu sabe que da pra fazer isso com o `translate` nas `transitions` e `animations` do css ??

Comment: Eu sei mas eu preciso de utilizar "tecnologias" que não aprendi na escola, por isso optei pelo jquery e pelo bootstrap