# jQuery Toggle animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou a tentar fazer uma animação que comporte como um toggle. O que eu quero é que com o click event no `#admin > p`, este se desvie para a esquerda enquanto o `#admin > form, #btn` slideUp e volte para a posição original (css) quando `#admin > form, #btn` faz slide down outra vez.

Aqui está o meu cóodigo:

```
$('#admin > p').click(function(){
    $('#admin > form, #btn').stop(true).slideToggle();
})

$('#admin > p').toggle(function() {
    $(this).animate({'left':'20px'});
}, function() {
    $(this).animate({'right':'20px'});
});
```

Comment: Miguel, pode adicionar o seu HTML para ficar mais claro? (ou mesmo fazser um jsFIddle)

Comment: Você quer que se um aparecer o outro desapareça, e vice-versa?

Comment: Aqui está o jsFiddle. Nota: não sei o que está a acontecer mas no meu browser funciona. O '#admin > p' vai para a esquerda mas o que que eu queria é que voltas-se dps para a posição original qd o 'form' fica-se hidden. Obgado pus este codigo porque ao menos funciona uma vez, tenho a certeza que percebem o que quero dizer. Obgado http://jsfiddle.net/dW6Mb/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aqui fica uma sugestão:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var aberto = $('#btn').is(':visible');  // verificar se #btn está visivel guardando o estado como true / false
    $('#admin > p').click(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            'right': aberto ? '20px' : '150px', // no caso de aberto se true usar '20px', no caso de aberto ser false usar '150px'
        });
        aberto = !aberto;
        $('#admin > form, #btn').stop(true).slideToggle();
    })
})
```

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/vU53x/6)

Não sei bem porque faz toggle da form `'#admin > form` e também do elemento `#btn` que está dentro da form e por isso incluído no `slideToggle()`. Se ele não fôr preciso pode também usar assim:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#admin > p').click(function () {
        var $adminForm = $('#admin > form');  // isto até poderia estar fora da função click caso seja usado noutras partes do código
        $(this).animate({
            'right': $adminForm.is(':visible') ? '20px' : '150px',
        });
        $adminForm.stop(true).slideToggle();
    })
})
```

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/vU53x/5/)

Comment: Miguel, recomento também dar uma olhada à minha resposta aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/7388/problema-com-jquery-ui-slide-left

Comment: Obgado sergio. Quanto ao #btn estar no form e por isso ter de sofrer o slide com o form estou de acordo e foi isso que fiz no inicio mas não estava a aparecer no slide show, e tive de o por com um id e display:none no css só assim é que resultou, não percebo também. Obgado

Comment: @Miguel fico contente de a minha resposta ter ajudado. Já agora, o `display: none;` no botão não é necessário, podes tirar: http://jsfiddle.net/vU53x/3/

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer isso usando classes para verificar o estado do form. Fiz algumas alterações no fiddle que vc enviou.

http://jsfiddle.net/dW6Mb/6/

Comment: Obgado Moykn, mas não sei porquê o teu codigo estava ok no jsfiddle mas não consegui implementar no meu

Comment: Se você apenas copiou o código(javascript) e jogou na sua página realmente não vai funcionar, fiz algumas alterações no html tbm.