# O que significa ? e : dentro de uma expressão?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu vi em um site o seguinte código:

```
var campo1 = document.getElementById('valor1').value;
var campo2 = document.getElementById('valor2').value;

var maior = (parseFloat(campo1) > parseFloat(campo2) ? campo1 : campo2);
var menor = (parseFloat(campo1) < parseFloat(campo2) ? campo1 : campo2);
```

A minha dúvida é, o que significa a colocação de: `>`, `<`, `?` e `:`,  dentro dessas variáveis.

Comment: Sinceramente não entendi muito sua dúvida, mas nesse caso esta sendo feito uma comparação `parseFloat(campo1) > parseFloat(campo2)` e o uso do `?` e `:` é operador ternário

Comment: É claro que isso não era uma dúvida e sim uma forma de ganhar like (up Vote), ridículo.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4907/diferentes-formas-de-if-e-else/

Comment: Eu sempre via esse simbolos e nunca entendia,  mas agora com a ajuda de todos está tudo claro, como deu pra perceber eu não sou nenhum expert em javascript, ai então eu perguntei isso aqui, e se eu posso ganhar alguma coisa com isso,  ganharei. Obrigado a todos que me ajudaram e desculpa s eu não fui claro a todos.

Comment: @EduardoBentoRochaJunior eu entendo perfeitamente sua colocação, essa foi uma das minhas primeiras questões no Meta, só estou compartilhando por ser um assunto já resolvido. Participe também, a opinião da comunidade é que molda o site! (nem tudo, infelizmente, pois inicialmente queriamos um SO sério, não um SO com jeitinho brasileiro, mas a "chefia" nao deixou).

Comment: @Bacco nada pessoal :D, vou participar sim.

Comment: O problema era que eu não sabia que o nome era ternário.

Comment: -1 por não demonstrar o mínimo empenho em ter procurado a resposta antes de postar a pergunta aqui. Essa sintaxe é comum em inúmeras linguagens, não é coisa de Javascript. A solução era mto fácil de achar! Me pareceu uma forma de ganhar pontos antes mesmo de ler os comentários da questão.

Comment: @SamirBraga a pergunta é válida, e útil para outras pessoas. Só editei por dois motivos: primeiro pra ficar mais simples de entender e sem aquele comentário desnecessário, segundo pra permitir que quem votou -1 por implicância possa rever o voto. De qq forma, eu votei positivo, mas teve muito voto negativo desnecessário. Pena que o pessoal não tem o mesmo empenho pra negativar coisas realmente com problema no site.

Comment: @AndréFigueiredo mas agora quando alguém procurar no google, há uma chance de achar o SOpt, que é um dos objetivos do site. Participe do http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com pra entender melhor a mecânica da coisa e contribuir com sua opinião.

Comment: Na minha opinião, eu entendo os objetivos do site e mecânica da coisa.. só acho que preciso contribuir com a minha opinião mesmo no meta, porque estou percebendo muito mineragem de pontos no SOPt com perguntas feitas parecendo carecer de qualquer empenho em sanar a dúvida antes de postar aqui. Mantenho minha opinião, a pergunta é até **duplicada** como mencionada num comentário anterior.

Comment: @Bacco De fato a maneira para se chegar à resposta é diferente, mas no fundo é a mesma pergunta. Aliás, [esse é o principal objetivo de marcar como duplicata - permitir que uma mesma pergunta expressa de formas totalmente diferentes se direcionem para o mesmo recurso](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/). Lembrando a todos que fechar uma pergunta não é uma "punição", em especial no caso de duplicatas - onde a pergunta pode ser bem feita, on topic, e o melhor curso de ação ainda ser fechar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso se chama **IF TERNÁRIO**

por exemplo:

```
var maior = (parseFloat(campo1) > parseFloat(campo2)? campo1 : campo2);
```

é o mesmo que

```
maior="";
if((parseFloat(campo1) > parseFloat(campo2))
{
  maior=campo1;
}else{
  maior=campo2;
}
```

ou seja depois do `?` ele executa se a condição for verdadeira e o `:` é se ela for falsa

**mais detalhes:** http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/be21c7hw(v=vs.94).aspx

Comment: Ótimo, me ajudou, exemplo simples e claro.

Comment: Concordo, seu exemplo é bem claro! Obrigado!

Comment: @SamirBraga ok, se minha resposta te ajudou por favor não esqueça de marca-la como certa.. ;)

Answer (score 6):

## O Operador ternário

```
 a ? b : c
```

> "Se `a` for verdadeiro, retorna `b`, senão retorna `c`"

Vamos analisar o exemplo dado:

```
 var maior = (parseFloat(campo1) > parseFloat(campo2)? campo1 : campo2);
```

Os `<` e `>` são os comparadores de maior e menor que você já deve conhecer. O que talvez seja uma novidade aí é o *operador ternário*, delimitado por `?` e `:`

Neste caso, primeiro é resolvida a comparação `parseFloat(campo1) > parseFloat(campo2)`. Se o resultado desta comparação for verdadeiro, a variável `maior` vai receber o valor do `campo1`. Caso contrario, vai receber o valor do `campo2`.

É equivalente ao IF inline (ou IIF) de algumas linguagens:

```
// Linguagem com operador ternário
print A > 10 ? "A é maior que dez" : "A é menor que dez"

// Linguagem com if inline
print if( A > 10, "A é maior que dez", "A é menor que dez" )
```

Comment: Obrigado, sua resposta é bem clara.

Comment: Os downvoters poderiam dizer o que tem errado nessa resposta pra gente que é mais burro aprender.

Answer (score 3):

É uma espressão ternaria de uma verificação.

A sintaxe é: `conditional ? true : false`.

Ou: `"se isso retornar true" ? "retorne isso" : "se não, retorne isso"`.

No seu caso, na variável `maior` você está verificando se `parseFloat(campo1)` é maior que (`>`) `parseFloat(campo2)`, caso seja, o valor da variável `maior` passa a ser o valor da variável `campo1`, caso o contrário passa a ser o valor da variável `campo2` e assim por diante.

Seria o mesmo que:

```
if(parseFloat(campo1) > parseFloat(campo2)) {
    var maior = campo1;
} else {
    var maior = campo2;
}
```

Porém de forma resumida.

Comment: Obrigado, sua resposta é bem clara.

Answer (score 3):

### Operador condicional ternário

Existe no javascript um operador que parece com um if/else, que serve para retornar um valor dada uma condição. Esse operador é um operador condicional ternário (que significa que ele possui três operandos). Sua forma é a seguinte:

```
condicao ? parte_verdadeira : parte_falsa;
```

> Se a condicao for avaliada como sendo verdadeira, a expressão retorna a `parte_verdadeira`, caso contrário retorna a `parte_falsa`.

Exemplo:

```
var x = valor > 10 ? "maior que 10" : "menor ou igual a 10";
```

### Expressão avalida como verdadeira: `condicao`

A condição é qualquer expressão que possa ser avaliada como verdadeira ou falsa. Note que eu não disse "é verdadeira" e sim "pode ser avaliada como verdadeira". Disse dessa forma, pois existem vários valores que não são verdadeiro/falso, mas podem ser avaliados como tal:

- 0 é avaliado como falso, e outros números como verdadeiro
- null e undefined são avaliados como falso
- string vazia é falso, qualquer outra string é verdadeiro

### Sobre a sua dúvida

Os sinais de `<` e `>` são apenas comparadores sendo usados na parte da condição do operador ternário.

Comment: Obrigado, sua resposta é bem clara.

Answer (score 2):

Simples, isto nada mais é que if e else de uma forma rápida
Quando parseFloat(campo1) > parseFloat(campo2), se for verdadeiro, a variavel recebe campo1, senão será o campo2.

Ainda existe x ?? y, aonde se x for diferente de nulo vai resultar x senão y.