# Dificuldade na Sintaxe

Tags: c, operadores, sintaxe, recursão

Gostaria que me explicassem esta função, não percebo esta sintaxe:

```
double sum_arithmetic(double x0, double r, int n)
{
    return n == 0 ? 0 : x0 + sum_arithmetic(x0 + r, r, n-1);
}
```

Comment: Tem algo específico que não está entendendo? É o operador ternário `? e :`, é a chamada da própria função?

Comment: esta função faz o mesmo que isto (n/2) * ((2 * x0) + ((n - 1) * (r))), mas não estou a perceber como pode ela calcular esta mesma formula. E não estou a perceber também o operador ternário :/

Comment: Recursividade em uma linha. O cara que fez isso é bem hardcore :D

Comment: poderiam explicar o que é a recursividade?

Comment: @BrunoRodrigues [recursividade](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursividade) é basicamente uma função que chama ela mesma como retorno.

Comment: Na verdade é alguém que passou algum tempo nas trincheiras com linguagens funcionais. Bruno, veja [o artigo sobre Recursividade](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursividade) na Wikipedia.

Comment: sendo assim pelo que percebi é algo mais ancestral ao ciclo for ou if por exemplo :D

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Operador ternário

O operador ternário se assemelha a um `if` mas é uma expressão e não um *statement*. Então você pode usar em qualquer lugar que aceite uma expressão, desde que os seus resultados também sejam expressões. Na verdade prefiro chamá-lo de condicional, já que ternário é circunstancial e não define o que ele faz.

Ele é composto de três partes (por isto é chamado erroneamente de operador ternário):

- A primeira parte (antes da interrogação) é a condição, é o que vai determinar verdadeiro ou falso (1 é verdadeiro e 0 é falso, igual ao `if`, igual qualquer condição), no seu exemplo `n == 0`.
- Depois ele tem (após a interrogação e antes dos dois pontos) a expressão que será considerada se a condição for verdadeira, no seu exemplo ´0´.
- E a última parte (após os dois pontos) é a expressão que será considerada se a condição for falsa, no seu exemplo `x0 + sum_arithmetic(x0 + r, r, n-1)`.

Sempre apenas uma delas será considerada.

Então você vai ler isto da seguinte forma:

Se `n` é igual a zero, considere como resultado zero, caso contrário faça o seguinte cálculo `x0 + sum_arithmetic(x0 + r, r, n-1)` e considere o resultado dele.

Seu código poderia ser escrito com `if` desta forma:

```
if (n == 0) {
    return 0;
} else {
    return x0 + sum_arithmetic(x0 + r, r, n-1);
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Operator/If.c).

O nome correto deveria ser operador condicional, mas como ele é o único operador ternário conhecido em linguagens *mainstream*, acabou pegando esse nome.

Alguma informação adicional [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17398/101) e [essa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/10539/101) e na [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation).

## Recursividade

É um conceito onde uma função chama ela mesma e, em geral, que tenha uma condição onde não seja mais necessário chamá-la (isto não é obrigatório mas se não tiver uma forma de saída, as chamadas serão infinitas e você acabará com um erro de *[stack overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow)*).

Tem uma piada que ajuda entender um pouco:

> Para entender recursão, você precisa entender o que é recursão. Entendeu?

Agora procure no Google pela palavra `recursion`. Vai achar outra piada.

Um exemplo clássico de recursividade é o cálculo do fatorial:

- O fatorial é 4 é:
- 4 vezes o fatorial de 3. Não ajudou muito, agora preciso saber qual é o fatorial de 3:
- 3 X 2!. Então agora calculo o fatorial de 2:
- 2.1!. E por convenção 1! é 1, então não preciso mais continuar com a recursão e o resultado é:
- 4.3.2.1 = 24.

Para saber mais veja [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4282/101) e na [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)).

## Seu exemplo

Enquanto o terceiro parâmetro `n` não for zero ele vai calcular a soma de `x0` com o resultado da própria função `sum_arithmetic()` passando como parâmetros o primeiro parâmetro `x0` somado do segundo parâmetro `r`, depois passará o próprio `r` e finalmente passa para o último parâmetro o `n` recebido subtraído de um. Como em cada chamada o `n` sempre vai sendo reduzido de um, uma hora vai chegar em zero e aí ele simplesmente vai retornar zero de acordo com o operador ternário, e não vai mais chamar a função.

Se tiver uma quantidade muito, muito grande de chamadas recursivas da função `sum_arithimetic()` é possível que você tenha um *stack overflow* por encher toda memória reservada para o *stack* da sua aplicação.

Comment: Muito obrigado, tudo explicado!!! :D

Comment: +1 pela resposta e +1 pela referência a recursão do google. hahahahaha