# O que significa isso em c++?

Tags: c++

Estava dando uma olhada em como usar templates em c++, quando me deparo com isso aqui  `return (a>b?a:b);`.
  ( http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/oldtutorial/templates/ )
O que é esse `?` no código?Tentei pesquisar no google mas não deu muito certo, parece que o `?` é ignorado na pesquisa...
Já tinha visto isso algumas vezes mas nunca me importei. Acredito eu ser algum tipo de formatação, do mesmo jeito que  `a = a + b` seja igual a `a+=b` , certo?

Comment: veja https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/34200/dificuldade-na-sintaxe

Comment: e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/44741/atribuir-uma-express%C3%A3o-a-uma-vari%C3%A1vel/44742#44742