# O que cada sinal significa nessa atribuição em C#?

Tags: c#

```
 mainSize = mainSize < 0 ? 20 : mainSize ;
```

O que significam o "?" e o ":" dentro dessa atribuição da variavel 'mainSize'?

Comment: Isso é um operador ternário: http://www.macoratti.net/14/11/c_tern1.htm

Comment: isto é uma ternária, funciona como um if/else

Comment: Outra: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4907/como-funciona-este-if-else-com-e/322979#322979 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/34200/dificuldade-na-sintaxe

Comment: é o mesmo que: `if (mainSize < 0)  mainSize = 20 else mainSize = mainSize`

Comment: @Barbetta, não acredito que estas duas sejam duplicadas, uma é `javascript` a outra `c++` e essa é `c#`.

Comment: @RobertodeCampos, eu sinalizei essas perguntas porque comportamento é o mesmo em todas. Realmente não pensei na questão linguagens diferentes, irei ver no Meta se há algo falando sobre isso.

Comment: @RobertodeCampos abri uma pergunta no meta: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7313/duplicada-com-linguagens-diferentes

Comment: Se as respostas (existentes e potenciais futuras) respondem à pergunta, o fechamento como duplicata é válido.

Answer (score 1):

Este é o operador ternário ([docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator)).

É uma versão encurtada e com um comportamento ligeiramente diferente do `if`.

Exemplo de uma condicional:

```
if (mainSize < 0)
    mainSize = 20;
else
    mainSize = mainSize;
```

É equivalente a:

```
mainSize = (mainSize < 0) ? 20 : mainSize ;
```

A *leve* diferença entre trocar o `if` por um ternário é que o ternário vai resultar em um dos dois valores (como se ele retornasse) enquanto um `if` vai executar o que estiver dentro do seu bloco de execução, não necessariamente retornando algo.

Exemplo, o `if` a seguir não pode ser representado como um ternário:

```
if (mainSize < 0)
    negativo = true;
else
    positivo = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mainSize = mainSize < 0 ? 20 : mainSize ;

? é igual ao if

if(mainSize < 0){
}

: igual ao else
else{

}

mainSize < 0 se 20 senão mainSize
```

Comment: A sua resposta, embora correta, ficou bem esquisita e confusa devido a má formatação. Sugiro também dar uma melhor trabalhada na redação.