# Como usar o operador ternário para determinar o que exibir?

Tags: javascript, operadores

Como posso usar corretamente o Operador Ternário em JavaScript. Tenho o Seguinte código:

```
var Requisitar = function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $.ajax({
        url: 'https://steamgaug.es/api/v2', // Acesso direto a API
        success: function(resposta){ // <-- variavel resposta vem com todos dados da API
            // Steam Loja Comunidade
            $("#dota2-statusapidota").html(resposta["IEconItems"]["570"]["online"]);
        }
        });
    Requisitar();
    },5000);//1000=a um segundo, altere conforme o necessario
};
Requisitar();//Dispara
```

Então Quando usado em HTML:

```
li id="dota2-statusapidota" < /li >
```

O valor mostrado é 1.

Como posso usar o operador ternário corretamente para que esse "1" seja exibido como "Online"?

JSON Recebido:

```
{
    "ISteamClient": {
        "online": 1
    },
    "SteamCommunity": {
        "online": 1,
        "time": 25,
        "error": "No Error"
    },
    "SteamStore": {
        "online": 1,
        "time": 2,
        "error": "No Error"
    },
    "ISteamUser": {
        "online": 1,
        "time": 20,
        "error": "No Error"
    },
    "IEconItems": {
        "440": {
            "online": 1,
            "time": 27,
            "error": "No Error"
        },
        "570": {
            "online": 1,
            "time": 27,
            "error": "No Error"
        },
        "730": {
            "online": 1,
            "time": 27,
            "error": "No Error"
        }
    },
    "ISteamGameCoordinator": {
        "440": {
            "online": 1,
            "schema": "http://media.steampowered.com/apps/440/scripts/items/items_game.b7f5e5dded37fbd6494d96690a71e507d28279f7.txt",
            "error": "No Error",
            "stats": {
                "spyScore": "0",
                "engiScore": "0"
            }
        },
        "570": {
            "online": 1,
            "error": "No Error",
            "stats": {
                "players_searching": 20509
            }
        },
        "730": {
            "online": 1,
            "error": "No Error",
            "stats": {
                "players_searching": 2310,
                "players_online": 111128
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Altamente relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4907/diferentes-formas-de-if-e-else, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10539/o-que-significa-e-dentro-de-uma-express%C3%A3o?lq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assim:

```
var online = resposta["IEconItems"]["570"]["online"];
$("#dota2-statusapidota").html(online === 1 ? "online" : "offline");
```

Coloquei o dado original numa variável pra facilitar a leitura. O uso do operador é simples: se `online` for `1`, a expressão retorna a string `"online"`, senão retorna `"offline"`.

```text
A ? B : C;
    ^   ^
    |   retornado se A não for verdadeiro
    |
    retornado se A for verdadeiro
```