# Executar javascript contando click para mostrar opção na tela?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um código que mostra campos na tela de acordo com o click, após o primeiro click ele vai incrementar uma variável 'QtdClick', ocorre que eu não queria que mostrasse todos os campos, quero apenas quando for o 2 segundo click, 3 click etc, individualmente.

Exemplo:

```
<script>


      $(document).ready(function(){

            //esconde o campo na abertura da página
            document.getElementById('extraum').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('extradois').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('extratres').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('extraquatro').style.display = 'none';

            //se o botão for clikado 1 vez, mostra o campo  
            var QtdClick = 1; //inicindo 
            var btn1 = document.querySelector("#mostracampo1");
            btn1.addEventListener('click',function(e){

            if (QtdClick ==1 ){
                document.querySelector("#extraum").style.display = 'block';
                QtdClick++;
                alert(QtdClick);
            }

            if (QtdClick ==2 ){
                document.querySelector("#extradois").style.display = 'block';
                QtdClick++;
                alert(QtdClick);
            }

            if (QtdClick ==3 ){
                document.querySelector("#extratres").style.display = 'block';
                QtdClick++;
                alert(QtdClick);
            }

            if (QtdClick ==4 ){
                document.querySelector("#extraquatro").style.display = 'block';
                QtdClick++;
                alert(QtdClick);
            }

          });

       });


    </script>
```

html:

```
<input type="text" required class="form-control" id="extraum" placeholder="campo 1">
   <input type="text" required class="form-control" id="extradois" placeholder="campo 2">
   <input type="text" required class="form-control" id="extratres" placeholder="campo 3">
   <input type="text" required class="form-control" id="extraquatro" placeholder="campo 4">

   <a href="#" id="mostracampo1" class="btn btn-custom  btn-branco btn-lg">Mostar Campo Botão</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Podes fazer isso com menos código, mais optimizado:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var QtdClick = 0; // iniciando 
  var inputs = ['extraum', 'extradois', 'extratres', 'extraquatro'].map(function(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
  });
  var btn1 = document.querySelector("#mostracampo1");
  btn1.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    inputs.forEach(function(input, i) {
      input.style.display = QtdClick == i ? 'block' : 'none';
    });
    QtdClick++;
  });
});
```

```css
input {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" required class="form-control" id="extraum" placeholder="campo 1">
<input type="text" required class="form-control" id="extradois" placeholder="campo 2">
<input type="text" required class="form-control" id="extratres" placeholder="campo 3">
<input type="text" required class="form-control" id="extraquatro" placeholder="campo 4">

<a href="#" id="mostracampo1" class="btn btn-custom  btn-branco btn-lg">Mostar Campo Botão</a>
```

As ideias no código são:

- coloca o `display = 'none';` inicial no CSS
- usa o indice do array de IDs para comparar com `QtdClick` e com um [ternário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/51479/129) escolhes de deve mostrar ou esconder.

Uma outra ideia, ainda mais escalável é nem usares IDs nos inputs, e ficaria assim:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var QtdClick = 0; // iniciando 
  var inputs = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('input'));
  var btn1 = document.querySelector("#mostracampo1");
  btn1.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    inputs.forEach(function(input, i) {
      input.style.display = QtdClick == i ? 'block' : 'none';
    });
    QtdClick++;
  });
});
```

```css
input {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" required class="form-control" placeholder="campo 1">
<input type="text" required class="form-control" placeholder="campo 2">
<input type="text" required class="form-control" placeholder="campo 3">
<input type="text" required class="form-control" placeholder="campo 5">
<input type="text" required class="form-control" placeholder="campo 6">
<input type="text" required class="form-control" placeholder="campo 7">
<input type="text" required class="form-control" placeholder="campo 8">
<input type="text" required class="form-control" placeholder="campo 9">
<input type="text" required class="form-control" placeholder="campo 10">
<input type="text" required class="form-control" placeholder="campo 11">

<a href="#" id="mostracampo1" class="btn btn-custom  btn-branco btn-lg">Mostar Campo Botão</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Já tenho a resposta:

```
<script>

      $(document).ready(function(){

            //esconde o campo na abertura da página
            document.getElementById('extraum').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('extradois').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('extratres').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('extraquatro').style.display = 'none';

            //se o botão for clikado 1 vez, mostra o campo  
            var QtdClick = 1; //inicindo 
            var btn1 = document.querySelector("#mostracampo1");
            btn1.addEventListener('click',function(e){

            while(QtdClick < 15){

                if(QtdClick ==1){
                  document.querySelector("#extraum").style.display = 'block';
                  QtdClick++;
                  alert(QtdClick);
                  break; 
                }

                if (QtdClick ==2 ){
                    document.querySelector("#extradois").style.display = 'block';
                    QtdClick++;
                    alert(QtdClick);
                    break; 
                }

                if (QtdClick ==3 ){
                    document.querySelector("#extratres").style.display = 'block';
                    QtdClick++;
                    alert(QtdClick);
                    break;
                }

                if (QtdClick ==4 ){
                document.querySelector("#extraquatro").style.display = 'block';
                QtdClick++;
                alert(QtdClick);
                break; 
            }

            }});

       });


    </script>
```