# condicionais dentro do if?

Tags: c, condição

Eu não sei se estou maluca kkkk mas acho que me lembro de ter visto condicionais simples dentro do printf. porém, não me lembro como faz.
tipl, ele faz a mesma coisa que isso:

```
if (xxx)
    printf("xxx");
else 
    printf("YYY");
```

só que tudo no mesmo printf. Tem como?

Comment: Tem o operador IF INLINE, ex: `printf( condicao ? "verdadeiro" : "falso" )` - Outras linguagens tem a função if ou iif como equivalente: `print( iif( x > 10, "v", "f" ) )` - O `? :` é chamado de "ternário" por uma grande maioria. Vale dizer que não é o melhor nome para ele, pois "ternário" significa que ele tem 3 "partes", mas não necessáriamente todo ternário em qualquer linguagem seja condicional.

Comment: Veja se o que procura é o que está nestes links: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/92101/70 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10539/70 - caso não seja isso, clique em [edit] e forneça mais detalhes do que precisa saber