# Qual a diferença entre pré e pós incremento em Javascript?

Tags: javascript

A forma mais comum e conhecida de incremento é o pós:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    console.log(i);
}
```

No entanto, seguidamente vejo o pré-decremento:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
    console.log(i);
}
```

No entanto, os resultados são os mesmos para esse exemplo.

Quais as diferenças entre pré e pós-incremento/decremento de uma variável em JavaScript?

Que ganhos essas diferenças podem trazer?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Pré-incremento

Veja o exemplo abaixo: no pré incremento, primeiramente  a variável `c` é incrementada, e só depois atribuída a `d`:

```
var c, d;
c=6;
console.log("Pre-incremento\n");
console.log("Numero sem incremento: %d\n", c); // 6
d=++c; // O VALOR É INCREMENTADO, E SÓ DEPOIS PASSADO PARA 'd'
console.log("Valor de 'c':%d\nValor de 'd':%d\n", c, d); // c = 7, d = 7
```

Neste exemplo, `c`, que vale 6 é primeiramente incrementada e passa a valer 7. Somente depois disso, a variável – que já vale 7 – é atribuída a ‘d’, que também fica valendo 7.

### Pós-Incremento

Veja no exemplo que primeiramente a variável é atribuída, e só depois incrementada:

```
var c, d;
c=6;
console.log("Pos-incremento\n");
console.log("Numero sem incremento: %d\n", c); // 6
d=c++;// O VALOR É PASSADO PARA 'd', E DEPOIS INCREMENTADO
console.log("Valor de 'c':%d\nValor de 'd':%d\n", c, d); // c = 7, d = 6
```

Neste exemplo, `c`, que vale 6 tem seu valor atribuído a `d`, que fica valendo 6 também. Somente depois dessa operação que `c` tem seu valor incrementado, valendo então 7.

> A mesma regra se aplica aos decrementos

### Pré-decremento

```
var c, d;
c=6;
console.log("Pre-decremento");
console.log("Numero sem incremento: %d", c); // 6
d=--c; // O VALOR É DECREMENTADO, E SÓ DEPOIS PASSADO PARA 'd'
console.log("Valor de 'c':%d\nValor de 'd':%d\n", c, d); // c = 5, d = 5
```

### Pós-decremento

```
var c, d;
c=6;
console.log("Pos-decremento");
console.log("Numero sem incremento: %d", c); // 6
d=c--; // O VALOR É PASSADO PARA 'd', E DEPOIS DECREMENTADO
console.log("Valor de 'c':%d\nValor de 'd':%d\n", c, d); // c = 5, d = 6
```

### Portanto

No seu exemplo pré ou pós incremento sempre resultarão no **mesmo resultado**, pois não há atribuição do valor de `i` a uma outra variável, você apenas está retornando o valor de `i` **após** a operação de incremento, seja ela pré ou pós.

Desta forma o seu exemplo funciona exatamente como:

```
c = 6;
c++; // o valor de 'c' é 7
console.log(c); // retornará 7
```

ou

```
c = 6;
++c; // o valor de 'c' é 7
console.log(c); // retornará 7
```

Answer (score 11):

O comportamento desses operadores de incremento têm relação com algo que já mencionei na [minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4916) a *[Como funciona este if/else com "?" e ":"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4907/diferentes-formas-de-if-e-else)*.

Imagine uma linha contendo somente isto:

```
i;
```

Dizemos que isso não faz nada e não serve pra nada, certo? Mas isso é válido na linguagem, então de alguma maneira é interpretado segundo as regras da linguagem (deixando de lado que pode haver otimizadores no meio do caminho simplesmente descartando essa linha de código). A linguagem interpreta `i` como uma *expressão*, e expressões sempre resultam em algo. No caso da nossa linha acima, supondo que `i` não exista, o resultado da expressão seria `undefined`.

Talvez já esteja claro aonde eu estou querendo chegar: `i++` e `++i` também são expressões (compostas da expressão `i` e de um dos operadores `++` – são dois, um usado como prefixo, e outro como sufixo). E assim, eles resultam em um valor, que pode ser utilizado em uma outra expressão que englobe essa, como uma atribuição:

```
var i = 0;
var x = i++;
var y = ++i;
```

E a diferença entre os operadores está justamente no comportamento do resultado da expressão: enquanto `i++` retorna o valor de `i` antes do incremento, `++i` primeiro incrementa `i`, e depois retorna o seu valor. Assim, no meu exemplo acima, o valor de `x` será `0`, e o de `y` será `2`.

Pegando os seus exemplos:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
```

e

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
```

O resultado das expressões `i++` e `++i` é diferente, mas não é usado. O que é usado, e só na linha seguinte, é o `i`. E o efeito das duas variantes sobre `i` *naquele momento* (linha seguinte) é equivalente.

Comment: Notei que tá ficando mais comum encontrar `++i` em laços for do que o "clássico" pós. Isso tem uma razão? Algum gosto pessoal de certos programadores? Talvez visando alguma manutenção? (ou talvez seja só impressão minha)

Answer (score 8):

Você somente notará diferença quando fizer uso do resultado do incremento, exemplo:

```
var i = 1;
i++;
console.log(i == 2); // true
// é o mesmo que
var i = 1;
++i;
console.log(i == 2); // true

//No exemplo abaixo não
var i = 1;
console.log(i++ == 2); // false
var i = 1;
console.log(++i == 2); // true
```

Quando utilizado em um loop, como no seu exemplo, não há diferença, pois `i++` retorna `i` e adiciona `1`, e `++i` adiciona `1` ao valor de `i` e retorna-o, portanto na primeira iteração, os dois terão o mesmo valor.

**Quanto a otimização**, o `pós-incremento` faz uso de uma variável temporária para armazenar o valor de `i` antes do incremento, já o `pré-incremento` adiciona o valor a variável original, no entanto isto é uma otimização prematura e de acordo com este [artigo](http://www.moddular.org/log/javascript-loops/), estatisticamente insignificante.

Comment: +1 pela resposta boa, e eu adoraria dar outro voto positivo pela referência ao artigo.

Comment: é.. pelo que parece ser mesmo ao meu ver, a otimização deve ser de 1 ou 2 opcodes.. micro-otimização desnecessária.

Answer (score -2):

1 - Acredito que usando "FOR" vai ser um pouco dificil compreender o trabalho do incremento. Tente com while (fica mais claro)

2- é melhor utilizar o incremento em uma variável a parte, segue exemplo:

```
{
    int i = 0;
    int var = 0;
    while (i < 10) {
        //var += ++i;
        var += i++;
        System.out.println("i= " + i + " | var= "+var);
    }
```

Alterando o incremento em "var" voce pode notar que mesmo com var++ antes do metodo print o valor impresso será [var = 0] O q significa que a variável altera após a execução do laço.
Falow...Valews!

Comment: A pergunta é especificamente sobre JavaScript, não Java.

Comment: E tem coisa errada aí...