# Como fazer uma função onde toda vez que que uma variável seja chamada esteja acrescida de mais 1?

Tags: php

Por exemplo,

em meio ao meu código eu faço

```
echo $num;  //me retorna 1, mas se eu ecoar novamente a variável "$num" 
            //me retornará 2   e assim sucessivamente.
```

Eu tentei de várias formas, mas não consegui:

```
function add_um(){  
}

add_um(); //Nesse caso toda vez que eu chamasse a função ela
//me traria um número diferente do anterior, sempre acrescentando 1 unidade.
```

Eu tentei com `while`, mas caiu num loop infinito 1234567...

**ACRESCENTADO:**

É possível usar a `$num` para nomear uma sessão? tipo, `$_SESSÃO[$num];` e depois nomear outra sessão hipoteticamente assim: `$_SESSÃO[$num++];` ?

Era disso que eu precisava. Nomear sessões automaticamente.

Eu pensei em usar o `for` para criar um `$i` que incrementaria(`i++`) a cada loop para nomear as sessões, mas já estou trabalhando dentro de um `for` e aí os loops iam ficar se repetindo.

Comment: Esse número é fixo ou passado como argumento?

Comment: porque não usar incremento 
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15800/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-pr%C3%A9-e-p%C3%B3s-incremento-em-javascript/15801#15801 na resposta é com javascript, mas com php a lógica é a mesma.

Comment: Fixo. Seria da própria função.

Comment: Eu sei que é com incremento. Penso que sei... Só não consegui construir. Vou olhar o link.

Comment: [SESSION-REF](http://php.net/manual/sr/session.examples.basic.php): `As chaves na $ _SESSION matriz associativa estão sujeitos às mesmas limitações que os nomes de variáveis ​​regulares do PHP, ou seja, eles não podem começar com um número e deve começar com uma letra ou sublinhado.` Qual o uso que você pretende?

Comment: Um simples `$_SESSION[]` resolveria seu problema? Criando um array associativo que inicia com 0? http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/db6ab48e7989a0f8e4919ee5d30ab5b607da4ac7

Comment: @gmsantos acrescentei detalhes à pergunta.

Comment: Não sei o que isso tem a ver com a questão original mas, se eu entendi corretamente, bastaria fazer **$_SESSION[] = array()** e armazenar todos os dados de que precise nesse array e, assim, o superglobal vai se comportar da forma mais básica que ele pode ser, isto é, um array, incrementando seus índices gradual e automaticamente.

Comment: Tem a ver porque eu precisava daquele conhecimento para fazer isso. Mas como através das respostas não consegui dar continuidade sozinho estou colocando mais pontos.

Comment: Cara desculpe, não quero ser rude, mas você precisa estudar um pouco mais de variáveis, arrays etc... vai lá no manual php e devora ele um pouco, faz testes com os exemplos do manual fora do seu script, para entender o funcionamento das coisas antes de tentar aplicar em algo mais complexo. E afinal o que é isso: `$i<$10` ?

Comment: @Jader isso foi só um erro de digitação, já corrigi. Bem, pode falar a verdade cara, não me ofendo com isso não. Eu aceito e concordo e tento. Estou desde de manhã estudando. Antes de postar aqui cara eu procuro em blogs, assisto video-aulas eu leio o manual, mas o manual é muito técnico para quem está aprendendo, não é como ler um livro de história que diz que fulano fez isso em tal ano e pronto você memorizou/aprendeu. Quando converso aqui no fórum minha mente abre. Não estou só a procura de códigos prontos e estou consciente que ninguém tem obrigação de postá=los para mim.

Comment: @Jader Mas enquanto estou correndo atrás, e já aprendi muito para quem estuda "sozinho", simplesmente pergunto para ver se não ganho ajuda. Mas sim vou estudar isso e as outras milhares de coisas que me faltam e seja sempre você, não gosto de falsidade. Obrigado por tudo que você já postou.

Comment: Por favor, tente não fazer uma pergunta-camaleão (que vai mudando de uma coisa pra outra). Se tiver novas dúvidas, faça novas perguntas. Votei pra fechar como "Não está claro o que está perguntado", pois a pergunta ficou bastante confusa...

Comment: Mudou completamente o sentido inicial da questão... o "echo ++" não se encaixa mais... A questão foi resolvida?

Comment: Do ponto de vista da pergunta inicial está sim resolvido. Devo eu remover o que não estiver no contexto da pergunta inicial? Eu pensei que poderia ir desenrolando as coisas.

Comment: Confesso que me perdi com tanta edição, por isso perguntei... e também não entendi qual a funcionalidade do que você está fazendo. Digo isso pois pode haver forma mais simples de se fazer.

Comment: @IWannaKnow, sim pode ir desenrolando as coisas mas através de novas perguntas, coloque um link pra esta aqui se ajudar a entender a nova. O modelo de um site Q&A é completamente diferente do de um fórum, confira o [tour] para saber mais.

Comment: Certo Brasófilo! Vou prestar mais atenção!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pra fazer isso numa variável:

```
$num = 0;
echo $num++ ;
echo $num++ ;
echo $num++ ;
echo $num++ ;
```

Usando passagem por referência:

```
function add_um( &$num ){  
   $num++;
}

$num = 0;
add_um( $num );
echo $num;
add_um( $num );
echo $num;
add_um( $num );
echo $num;
```

ou mesmo

```
function add_um( &$num ){  
   $num++;
   echo $num;
}

$num = 0;
add_um( $num );
add_um( $num );
add_um( $num );
```

Usando global (não recomendo):

```
function add_um(){  
   global $num;
   $num++;
}

$num = 0;
add_um();
```

> O global foi um exemplo genérico, tem mil formas de se fazer isso.

Comment: Se entendi bem a pergunta, melhor não complicar e usar direto `$num++` como no seu primeiro exemplo.

Comment: @bfavaretto concordo. Coloquei algumas possibilidades pra ter um ponto de partida apenas, mas realmente faltam detalhes na pergunta.

Comment: Grato! Acrescentei uma dúvida à pergunta.

Answer (score 11):

Uma outra possibilidade seria usando métodos mágicos.

<sub>**exemplo**</sub>

```
$counter = new Counter();
echo $counter;
echo $counter;
echo $counter;

echo $counter, $counter, $counter;
```

<sub>**output**</sub>

```
123
```

<sub>**class**</sub>

```
class Counter
{
    public static $counter = 0;

    public function __toString()
    {
        static::$counter++;
        return (string) static::$counter;
    }
}
```

---

Sempre que você der `echo` em uma variável contendo o objeto, será executado o incrementador ++ do método `__toString`.

<sub>**PHP**</sub>

> O método __toString() permite que uma classe decida como se comportar quando for convertida para uma string. Por exemplo, o que echo $obj; irá imprimir. Este método precisa retornar uma string, senão um erro nível E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR é gerado.

Comment: Apesar de curto, esse é um dos códigos PHP mais bem escritos que eu já vi, parabéns.

Comment: :) Obrigado, é vicio de `Programador-Designer` (rs)

Comment: *Tchi munitchinho...* Rolou até uma lagriminha masculina com esse código.

Comment: Então eu fui pesquisar e vi que **método mágico** é realmente um termo técnico do jargão do PHP. Isso fez o meu dia, +1.

Comment: Valeu @Bruno Augusto :)

Comment: @Renan, mais [método mágico](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.magic.php)

Comment: *LOL too much* pra **lagriminha masculina** do @BrunoAugusto (((: PHP++ pra mágica apresentada pelo Papa Charlie

Comment: emotion-code (LOL ++)

Comment: Acho que eu tava bem humorado hoje. Isso é tão.. raro.

Comment: Obrigado! Acrescentei uma dúvida na pergunta.

Answer (score 2):

Tem duas formas simples de fazer isso, e com resultados ligeiramente diferentes, veja qual se encaixa melhor na sua necessidade:

```
$num = 1;

echo $num++ . '<br>'; // retorna o valor atual da variável (que é 1) e soma + 1 (fica 2)

echo $num++ . '<br>'; // retorna o valor atual da variável (agora é 2) e soma + 1 (fica 3)

echo $num++ . '<br>'; // retorna o valor atual da variável (agora é 3) e soma + 1 (fica 4)

// e assim sucessivamente...

// retorno:
1
2
3

// ou desta forma:
$num = 1;

echo ($num += 1) . '<br>'; // Soma + 1 e retorna o novo valor da variável (que fica 2)

echo ($num += 1) . '<br>'; // Soma + 1 e retorna o novo valor da variável (que fica 3) 

echo ($num += 1) . '<br>'; // Soma + 1 e retorna o novo valor da variável (que fica 4)

// retorno:
2
3
4
```

Para cada requisição da pagina, o contador somar 1, basta fazer assim:

```
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['num'])) $_SESSION['num'] = 0;

$num =& $_SESSION['num'];

echo $num++;
```

Lembrando que isso é por sessão, ou seja, cada usuário terá um contador independente enquanto a sessão dele estiver viva...

Comment: Obrigado! Acrescentei uma dúvida na pergunta.

Comment: @IWannaKnow ficou bem confusa a sua duvida, mas acho que é isso que coloquei na resposta...

Comment: Mas antes eu tenho que declarar $num=0; certo? Dentro do colchete é num sem $ mesmo?

Comment: @IWannaKnow editei a resposta, sim índices de array devem ser usados assim mesmo com aspas e sem o $, a menos que o nome ou valor do índice seja o valor da variável...

Comment: Certo, mas eu não entendi uma coisa. Você setou o nome da sessão como "num", isso não é uma palavra? Como vou incrementá-la com o $num++?

Comment: @IWannaKnow ao usar o operador de atribuição por referencia `=&` faz com que uma variável fique relacionada a outra, ou seja, elas sempre terão o mesmo valor, veja mais no [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php)...

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16699/discussion-between-jader-and-i-wanna-know).