# Uso de incrementos em C

Tags: c

Qual a diferença no uso de incrementos em linguagem C, considerando um inteiro N?

```
N++
++N
N--
--N
```

Comment: Talvez responda(sei que são linguaguens diferentes): [Qual a diferença entre pré e pós incremento em Javascript?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15800/91)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A expressão `++n` incrementa o valor e então retorna o valor incrementado.

E na expressão `n++` retorna primeiro o valor de `n` e em seguida o valor é incrementado. É uma sutil diferença e o copilador trabalha da mesma forma para o decremento `n--` ou `--n`.

Em um **loop for** você pode usar o `++n`, é levemente mais rápido. Já, `n++` em um **loop for** irar criar uma copia extra do seu valor que sera jogada fora, mais isso não é motivo para não usar o `n++` no **loop for**, a não ser que você esteja programando para um hardware onde a memória é extremamente limitada, assim seria justificável usar `++n` no **loop for**.

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853/what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-i

Comment: Só adicionando que o comportamento do ++n é mais fácil de prever e por isso ele costuma ser recomendado acima do n++.

Comment: "Em um loop for você pode usar o ++n, é levemente mais rápido." Normalmente o compilador otimiza esses casos e o resultado final é equivalente n++

Answer (score 1):

O incremento tem a variação para cada caso que você queira usar. ex:

```
int x = 10;
int y = 10;
printf("%i",x++); // imprime 10
printf("%i",x);  // imprime 11
printf("%i",++y); // imprime 11
printf("%i",y); // imprime 11
```

o incremento ou decremento apos a variável, retorna a variável antes de alterar o valor, já antes da variável, faz a alteração e depois retorna.

Answer (score 1):

Trata-se dos conceitos de pré e pós incremento. E o mesmo se aplica para decremento também.

Sendo:

```
y = 0;
x = 10;
```

**Pré incremento**

```
y = ++x;
y = 11;
```

Equivale a seguinte atribuição:

```
x++;
y = x;
```

Ou seja, incrementa o `x` para depois atribui o novo valor de `x` a `y`.
________________________________________________________________________

**Pós incremento**

```
y = x++;
y = 10;
```

Equivale a seguinte atribuição:

```
y = x;
x++;
```

Ou seja, atribui o valor de `x` a `y`, para depois incrementar `x`.