# Qual é a diferença entre i++ e ++i?

Tags: java

Encontrei um trecho de código em uma aplicação que estou dando continuidade que não tinha visto ainda (ou nunca tinha reparado). Casualmente sempre usei `i++` em um laço de repetição, por exemplo, no entanto nesse trecho constava `++i` e não percebi nenhuma diferença no resultado. Veja abaixo um exemplo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Existe alguma diferença entre `i++` e `++i`? Se sim, qual(is) seria(m)?

Comment: Relacionado: [Qual a diferença entre pré e pós incremento em Javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15800/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-pr%C3%A9-e-p%C3%B3s-incremento-em-javascript)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Há uma diferença ligeira entre os dois. O `i++` (*"pós incremento"*) retorna o valor inicial de `i` e o `++i` (*"pré incremento"*)  retorna o valor incrementado de `i`.

Exemplo:

```
int i = 0;
int j = 0;

int a = i++; // a = 0, i = 1
int b = ++j; // b = 1, j = 1
```

**Ideone:** https://ideone.com/TPk7Qs

Este comportamento é igual em várias línguas, por exemplo em PHP e JavaScript, e funciona também com decremento.

Comment: Só para complementar: colocar os `++` **antes** da variável tem o nome de operação de _pré incremento_ e colocar os `++` **depois** da variável tem o nome de operação de _pós incremento_. Também é valido para operações de subtração: `--i` (_pré decremento_) e `i--` (_pós decremento_).

Comment: @IgorVenturelli obrigado! Juntei à resposta para ficar mais completa.

Comment: Relacionado: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/e1e3921c.aspx

Comment: Curiosidade: esses operadores como `++` [nasceram na linguagem B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Increment_and_decrement_operators), precursora do C, por isso aparecem na maioria das derivadas de C.

Answer (score 7):

Para o exemplo apresentado no laço de repetição `for` tanto o pré incremento:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
```

Como o pós incremento:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
```

Acabam por ser iguais, resultando apenas numa diferença de estilo de escrita.

**A diferença só se dá quando utilizamos a variável que está a ser incrementada no momento em que é incrementada**.

Tentando mostrar um exemplo diferente das outras respostas, considere um array e uma variável que indica a posição que se pretende alterar:

```
int[] arr = new int[10];
int pos = 0;
```

Agora fazendo:

```
arr[pos++] = 10;
```

Vai fazer com que a posição `0` tenha `10` e o `pos` fique com `1` após a instrução terminar, uma vez que o incremento é feito depois.

Ao passo que:

```
arr[++pos] = 10;
```

Vai primeiro aumentar o `pos` e colocar o `10` já na posição `1`.

Answer (score 3):

É a ideia de pós e pre-incremento, o mesmo acontece no caso do -- ...
i++ é o pós-incremento ou seja o i só vai ser incrementado após a linha de código ser executada, é no ++i é o pre-incremento no caso o i vai ser incrementado antes da linha de código ser executada por completo

Answer (score 2):

Uma vez fiz isso no Solo Learn, e o pessoal curtiu a simplicidade:

```
<?php

    # Antes
    $a = 5;
    $b = $a++;
    echo "b = ".$b; // b = 5

    echo "<hr>";

    # Depois
    $x = 5;
    $y = ++$x;
    echo "y = ".$y; // y = 6

?>
```