# teste de mesa incrementação

Tags: c

Não entendi de maneira alguma e estou há horas tentando compreender essas duas funções. Por que sai esses resultados?

Fiz dezenas de testes de mesa e nenhum bate.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x=0,y=0,z=0;
    for(z=0;z<7;z++)
        if((++x>2) && (y++>4))
        x++;
        printf("x: %d  y: %d\n",x,y); 
}
```

Isso exibe x=5 e y=7.

---

No outro caso a função é:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x=0,y=0,z=0;
    for(z=0;z<5;z++)
        if((++x>3) || (++y>2))
        x++;
        printf("x: %d  y: %d\n",x,y); 
}
```

Nesta exibe-se x=8  y=3

Comment: tenho dificuldade em compreender o "x++ vs ++x"

Answer (score 3):

A diferença é que `++x` primeiro incrementa o valor de `x`, e só depois usa esse valor para o que quer que ele esteja sendo usado. Já `x++` primeiro usa o valor de `x` na expressão, e só depois incrementa. Um exemplo simples:

```
int x = 0;
if (x++ > 0) {
    printf("entrou no if\n");
}
printf("%d\n", x);
```

Esse exemplo primeiro usa o valor de `x` na comparação. Como `x` vale zero, `x > 0` não é verdadeiro, então não entra no `if`. Depois que o `x` é usado na comparação, ele é incrementado, e o código imprime:

> 1

Agora se fizermos:

```
int x = 0;
if (++x > 0) {
    printf("entrou no if\n");
}
printf("%d\n", x);
```

Nesse caso, primeiro `x` é incrementado e seu valor passa a ser 1. Depois disso ele é usado na comparação `x > 0` (que agora é verdadeira, já que `x` vale 1). Por isso o código imprime:

> entrou no if
>   1

---

Sendo assim, vamos entender os códigos.

```
int x = 0, y = 0, z = 0;
for(z = 0; z < 7; z++)
    if((++x > 2) && (y++ > 4))
        x++;
printf("x: %d  y: %d\n", x, y);
```

O `for` vai executar 7 vezes. Como o `z` não é usado dentro do loop (ele é usado somente para controlar a quantidade de vezes que o `for` roda), podemos simplesmente analisar os valores de `x` e `y` a cada uma das 7 iterações.

Lembrando que, como temos `&&`, isso quer dizer que ambas as condições devem ser verdadeiras para entrar no `if`. Se a primeira for falsa, ele sequer avalia a segunda.

Na primeira iteração, `++x > 2` incrementa `x`, que passa a valer 1. Então a comparação `> 2` é falsa, e por isso a segunda condição sequer é testada. Então agora temos que `x` vale 1 e `y` continua sendo zero (e não entra no `if`).

Na segunda iteração, `x` é incrementado para 2, a condição `> 2` é falsa e `y` nem é avaliado, e portanto continua sendo zero (e ainda não entra no `if`).

Na terceira iteração, `x` é incrementado para 3 e agora a condição `> 2` é verdadeira. Mas como `&&` exige que ambas as condições sejam verdadeiras, ele precisa testar `y`. Então `y++ > 4` primeiro testa a condição `> 4` (que é falsa, pois `y` é zero) e em seguida incrementa `y`, que passa a valer 1. Por isso ainda não entra no `if`.

Na quarta iteração, `x` é incrementado para 4 e a condição `> 2` é verdadeira. Então `y++ > 4` testa a condição `> 4`, que ainda é falsa (pois `y` ainda vale 1) e `y` é incrementado para 2. E ainda não entra no `if`.

Na quinta iteração, `x` é incrementado para 5 e a condição `> 2` é verdadeira. Então `y++ > 4` testa a condição `> 4`, que ainda é falsa (pois `y` ainda vale 2) e `y` é incrementado para 3. E ainda não entra no `if`.

Na sexta iteração, `x` é incrementado para 6 e a condição `> 2` é verdadeira. Então `y++ > 4` testa a condição `> 4`, que ainda é falsa (pois `y` ainda vale 3) e `y` é incrementado para 4. E ainda não entra no `if`.

Na sétima iteração, `x` é incrementado para 7 e a condição `> 2` é verdadeira. Então `y++ > 4` testa a condição `> 4`, que ainda é falsa (pois `y` ainda vale 4) e `y` é incrementado para 5. E ainda não entra no `if`.

Como o `for` só executa 7 vezes, o loop termina, com `x` igual a 7 e `y` igual a 5.

---

```
int x = 0, y = 0, z = 0;
for(z = 0; z < 5; z++)
    if((++x > 3) || (++y > 2))
        x++;
printf("x: %d  y: %d\n", x, y);
```

De maneira similar, o loop executa 5 vezes. Mas agora o `if` possui `||`, que significa que se uma das condições for verdadeira, é o suficiente. Por isso, se a primeira for verdadeira, ele nem testa a segunda.

Na primeira iteração, `x` é incrementado para 1 e a comparação `> 3` é falsa. Mas o `||` só precisa que uma das condições seja verdadeira, então ele testa a próxima. `y` é incrementado para 1 e o teste `> 2` é falso. Então não entra no `if`.

Na segunda iteração, `x` é incrementado para 2 e a comparação `> 3` é falsa. `y` é incrementado para 2 e o teste `> 2` é falso. Então não entra no `if`.

Na terceira iteração, `x` é incrementado para 3 e a comparação `> 3` é falsa. `y` é incrementado para 3 e o teste `> 2` é verdadeiro. Então agora entra no `if`, incrementando `x` para 4.

Na quarta iteração, `x` é incrementado para 5 e a comparação `> 3` é verdadeira. Como o `||` só precisa que uma das condições seja verdadeira, ele nem testa a outra (então `y` permanece sendo 3). E como a primeira comparação foi verdadeira, ele entra no `if`, incrementando `x` para 6.

Na sexta iteração, `x` é incrementado para 7, a comparação `> 3` é verdadeira, entra no `if` e `x` é incrementado para 8.

No final, temos que `x` é 8 e `y` é 3.

Answer (score 1):

Os valores retornam diferente devido à forma como o código é executado. Os operadores `x++` (pós incremento) e `++x` (pré incremento) executam em momentos diferentes a soma de 1 ao valor da variável.

Veja [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/15801/7499) para mais detalhes sobre os operadores de pré e pós incremento.

Quando você usa `condicao1 || condicao2`, a primeira condição é avaliada sempre; a segunda condição só é avaliada caso a primeira seja falsa. Ao usar `condicao1 | condicao2`, as duas são avaliadas, independente do valor da primeira.

Comment: no segundo caso pq que quando chega no y=3 ele para de contar

Comment: por um acaso quando entra o || dentro do if e a primeira condiçao ja deu verdadeira, ele para de usar a segunda condiçao e por isso nao incrementou mais no y?

Comment: Resposta atualizada.

Comment: caaraaaaaaaaamba, estou desde 4h da tarde fazendo test de mesa, varias folhas kkkkk muito obrigado!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Fico feliz que tenha compreendido! Não esqueça de marcar a pergunta como resolvida.