# Comportamento do operador unário em JS usando comparação

Tags: javascript, operadores

De acordo com o código abaixo, foi declarado duas variáveis. Sendo a primeira variável foi aplicado a forma **pos-fixada** e a segunda **pré-fixada**.

Porém quando comparamos as duas variáveis retornam `true`. Contudo quando é comparado pelo operador de "comparação" pelo meu raciocínio era pra ter retornado `false`?. Pois estou fazendo uma comparação de tipo e valor.

```js
let num1 = 1;
let num2 = 2;

num1++; // Incrementa 1
console.log(num1);
--num1; // Decrementa 1
console.log(num1);

console.log(++num1 === num2--) //console: true
```

Comment: Existem 3 operadores nesse caso: `++`, `===` e `--`. Se voce analisar nesta ordem, deve retornar `true`. Veja => 1) Primeiro incremente `num1`; 2) depois compare o valor de **incrementado** `num1` com `num2` (ou seja `2 === 2` que é `true`); 3) decremente o valor de `num2` (que resulta em `num2` igual a `1`). Ou seja, quando você decrementou `num2`, a comparação já foi feita e retornou `true`.

Comment: Agora entendi o logica de comparação.

Comment: Não entendo porque negativaram a pergunta, pessoal em vez de ajudar acaba atrapalhando.

Comment: Se trocar o último `console.log(++num1 === num2--)` por `console.log(++num1, num2--)` irá notar que ambos obtiveram o mesmo valor, ambas ficaram com o valor `2`, logo comparar com === será *true*. Segue as respostas sobre pré e pós incremento/decremento: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15800/3635 e sobre operador de igualdade estrita: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/7/3635

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O sinal de incremento na **DIREITA** da variável dentro do console.log()
indicara primeiro imprime a variável e DEPOIS incrementa.

Sinal a **ESQUERDA** indica PRIMEIRO incrementa e DEPOIS imprime a variável.

Foi incrementado um valor na variável num1 e depois foi mostrada no console.

```
num1++; // Incrementa 1
console.log(num1);
```

Usou decremento logo abaixo, mas não dentro do console, que depois imprimiu no console

```
--num1
```

ultimo console.log

primeiro incrementou e tentou comparar o tipo  e depois imprimiu a
variável num2 e DEPOIS decrementou.

```
console.log(++num1 === num2--)
```

**num2--** primeiro foi impresso o valor atual e depois decrementou.

Mudar o sinal de decremento ajudara a ter o resultado diferente

**--num2**

```
console.log(++num1 === --num2)
```