# jQuery unbind a tudo, quando tamanho da window <= 800

Tags: jquery

Gostaria que todas as acções programadas com JavaScript ficassem sem efeito quando a `$(window).width() <= 800` para evitar conflitos entre layout Mobile e desktop. Mas a verdade é que fica sem CSS mas as acções (eventos) definidas no JavaScript continuam a acontecer e eu gostava que parasse tudo, como se nada estivesse definido em jQuery. Eu tenho o seguinte código mas não funciona:

HTML:

```
....
<link rel="stylesheet" media='screen and (min-width: 801px)' href ="css/styles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media='screen and (max-width: 800px)' href ="css/stylesMob.css">

<!-- HTML -->

....

//JQUERY

....

//isto no final da página

if ($(window).width() < 800) {
    $('*').off();
}
$(window).resize(function(){
    if ($(window).width() < 800) {
        $('*').off();
    }
})
```

Para uma visão mais detalhada aqui fica o [site.](http://iwanttobesanta.com/Touch_and_pizza/)

Comment: O que faz o jQuery que queres bloquear? são eventos click ou também `change`? se fôr só clics podes usar CSS pointer events... (o link que deste não funciona)

Comment: Tudo, porque vou usar os mesmos elementos (id's e classes) para window <= 800. e não gostava que houvesse conflitos, a unica coisa que vai mudar é o ficheiro de css. Gostaria que para window < 800 fosse um jquery novo

Comment: "Um jQuery novo" parece-me dificil e/ou trabalhoso. Nesse caso o mais seguro é ter uma flag e checkar essa condição em todos os pedaços de código. Se colocares o jQuery que queres "desligar" a pergunta fica mais clara.

Comment: Será possível especificar, tal como fiz com os ficheiros css em cima, ficheiros .js para um diferentes tamanhos da window? Se for possivel parece-me uma otíma solução. Ou envolver todo o meu código js na condição: 'if(($window).width() > 800) { // Todo o codigo feito para desktop } else { //layout Mobile }'

Comment: Miguel juntei uma resposta. A tua sugestão de fazer `if(($window).width() > 800) { // Todo o codigo feito para desktop } else { //layout Mobile }` também é uma alternativa, ou ainda `pointer-event: none;` dentro de uma media query. Coloca aqui o jQuery respetivo para ver qual das variantes é a melhor e mais simples de manter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes testar esta ideia dentro da tag HEAD da página:

```
<script>
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = screen.width > 800 ? 'scriptDesktop.js' : 'scriptMobile.js';    
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
</script>
```

Este script insere código de um ficheiro externo. Qual o ficheiro a ser inserido é escolhido aqui:

```
script.src = screen.width > 800 ? 'scriptDesktop.js' : 'scriptMobile.js';
```

e esse [operador ternário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4908/129) dá *desktop* se a condição `screen.width > 800` fôr verdadeira e *mobile* se fôr falsa.

Comment: Muito Obgado @Sergio, mais 'uma' na minha 'caixa de ferramentas'. Mas sim, acho que vou optar pela solução de cima.

Comment: Olá @Sergio, só para dizer que avancei com esta solução. a minha implementação final está em baixo. Obgado

Answer (score 0):

A minha implementação final, com a ajuda do @Sergio acabou por ser:

Dentro da tag head, no HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var type = 'text/javascript';
        var src = ($(window).width() > 800) ? "js/desktopLayout.js" : "js/mobileLayout.js";
        $('head').append('<script type ="' +type+ '" src="' +src+ '">');

    $(window).resize(function(){
        $('script[src $= "Layout.js"]').remove();
        var type = 'text/javascript';
        var src = ($(window).width() > 800) ? "js/desktopLayout.js" : "js/mobileLayout.js";
        $('head').append('<script type ="' +type+ '" src="' +src+ '">');
    })

</script>
```

PS:  Cada vez que fazemos resize estamos a acrescentar 'script type ="' +type+ '" src="' +src+ '"', função remove é para evitar isso, ou seja, no 'início' do resize vai eliminar o link atual para o ficheiro (desktopLayout ou mobileLayout).