# Tentando condensar condicional com três possibilidades

Tags: php, estilo-de-codificação, refatoração, condição

O problema é apresentar um resultado flexionando ao plural se necessário, ou "nenhum":

Seja ni>=0 (número de itens):

```
switch(true){
        case  $ni==0:
            $html = ' (nenhum)';
            break;
        case $ni==1:
            $html = ' (1 item)';
            break;
        case $ni>1:
            $html = ' ('.$ni.' itens)';
            break;
    }
```

Este está funcionando, agora com ifs, um pouco menor:

```
if($ni > 1){
        $html = ' ('.$ni.' itens)';
    } else if($ni == 1){
        $html = ' (1 item)';
    } else {
        $html = ' (nenhum)';
    }
```

Também funciona, mas agora a forma condensada que tentei fazer:

```
$html = ($ni > 1)? ' ('.$ni.' itens)' : ($ni==1)? ' (1 item)' : ' (nenhum)' ;
```

Este não funciona, ele responde "nenhum" corretamente, "1 item" corretamente, mas para ni>1 responde sempre "1 item".

A idéia é condensar um if, else if, else em uma linha, mas não se se é possível, já que a lógica parece correta. Existe outra forma condensada?

Comment: Só uma observação, acho que o termo correto seria "operador ternário" do que "forma condensada".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Falta colocar parênteses na condicional aninhada:**

```
$html = ($ni > 1) ? ' ('.$ni.' itens)' : (($ni==1) ? ' (1 item)' : ' (nenhum)');
//                                       ^                                    ^
```

Sem isso, o PHP [prioriza a primeira sequência de `?:` que encontra](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php), e o código é entendido assim:

```
$html = (($ni > 1) ? ' ('.$ni.' itens)' : ($ni==1)) ? ' (1 item)' : ' (nenhum)';
```

Se `$ni` for `2`, isso acaba interpretado assim:

```
$html = ((2 > 1) ? ' (2 itens)' : 2==1)) ? ' (1 item)' : ' (nenhum)';
```

Portanto:

```
$html = (true ? ' (2 itens)' : false)) ? ' (1 item)' : ' (nenhum)';
```

E então:

```
$html = ' (2 itens)' ? ' (1 item)' : ' (nenhum)';
```

Ou seja:

```
$html = true ? ' (1 item)' : ' (nenhum)';
```

E finalmente:

```
$html = ' (1 item)';
```

De qualquer maneira, [eu acho isso pouco legível](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4916/74)<sup>1</sup>. É uma questão de opinião, mas das 3 opções que você testou, eu prefiro os `if`s.

<sub>(1) No link eu estou falando sobre JavaScript, mas esse operador funciona igual nas duas linguagens (e em outras)</sub>

Comment: Funcionou beleza! De fato, os ifs são mais agradáveis, também acho, mas há outra questão: lido com várias linguagens e às vezes as múltiplas definições não são adequadas. Além disso, caso precise usar muitas vezes, será mais prático copiar e colar uma única linha. E além disso é um exercício divertido!

Comment: Concordo. Também prefiro os `if`s nesse caso. O `switch(true)` nunca vi alguém usar, e o ternário, quando são aninhados fica pouco legível mesmo.

Comment: Acho que você poderia melhorar o texto daquele link porque em versões recentes (relativamente falando) **?:** é uma variante curta do operador ternário (que eu nunca entendi como funciona >.<) e pode causar confusão.

Answer (score 5):

Só uma alternativa de implementação se estiver [usando o PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/migration55.new-features.php):

```
$html = [' (nenhum)', ' (1 item)', ' ('.$ni.' itens)'][($ni > 1) ? 2 : $ni];
```

Eu acho mais simples assim. Não gosto de duplo condicional em operador ternário.

É possível fazer o mesmo antes da versão 5.5 mas não fica tão simples (pelo menos comparando com a versão do duplo ternário):

```
$textos = [' (nenhum)', ' (1 item)', ' ('.$ni.' itens)'];
$html = $textos[($ni > 1) ? 2 : $ni];
```

Isto ainda exige o PHP 5.4. Para versões anteriores:

```
$textos = array(' (nenhum)', ' (1 item)', ' ('.$ni.' itens)');
$html = $textos[($ni > 1) ? 2 : $ni];
```

Com `if` para quem prefere (cada vez vai ficando menos vantajoso):

```
$textos = array(' (nenhum)', ' (1 item)', ' ('.$ni.' itens)');
if($ni > 1) {
    $html = $textos[2];
} else {
    $html = $textos[$ni];
}
```

Finalmente aproveitando outras respostas postadas como eu faria nesta situação:

```
function pluralization( $numItems = 0, $texts) {
    if ($texts == NULL) {
        $texts = array("(nenhum)", "(1 item)", "($numItems itens)");
    }
    return $texts[min($numItems, 2)];
}

echo pluralization(0);
echo pluralization(0);
echo pluralization(1);
echo pluralization(2);
echo pluralization(3);
$elementos = 4; // podia usar o letral direto mas no uso real vai fazer mais sentido com uma variável
echo pluralization($elementos, ["nada", "um elemento", "$elementos elementos"]);
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/wPXaoL). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/fbjtedga-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/String/Plural.php).

Comment: Neste caso não acho que ocorra o mesmo já que tem apenas uma condição. Eu particularmente faria assim mas acho perfeitamente válido que outras pessoas prefiram o uso do `if` e eu faria uso dele também se minha equipe preferisse assim. Mas agora fiz uma versão com `if`.

Answer (score 4):

Versão sem if:

Eu normalmente faria isso em PHP 5.4+ (que permite acesso direto a *arrays*):

```
$ni = 6;
echo array('nenhum', 'um ítem', "$ni ítens")[min($ni,2)];
```

5.5 (nao lembro se o 5.4 ja permite)

```
echo ['nenhum', 'um ítem', "$ni ítens"][min($ni,2)];
```

Em PHP 5.3- não é tão elegante, pois precisa de variável, mas fica bem em uma função:

```
echo humano( 0 )."\n";
echo humano( 1 )."\n";
echo humano( 2 )."\n";
echo humano( 3 )."\n";
echo humano( 4 )."\n";

function humano($ni) {
   $out = array( 'nenhum', 'um ítem', "$ni ítens");
   return $out[min($ni,2)];
}
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/kPwYPN)**.

Answer (score 3):

Todas as respostas lidam perfeitamente com o problema, inclusive algumas soluções na pergunta.

Vou deixar uma sugestão que vai muito ao encontro do já salientado em alguns comentários e respostas que passa por deixar o código reduzido sim, mas com leitura para que no futuro seja rápido analisar o mesmo:

**Exemplo**

```php
$html = ' (nenhum)';

if ($ni >= 1) {

    $html = ($ni == 1) ? ' (1 item)' : ' ('.$ni.' itens)';
}
```

O meu modelo passa por ter um valor por defeito.
Esse valor será subscrito apenas se necessário.
A subscrição do mesmo tem em conta o plural com base na quantidade de itens.

Ver exemplo para `$ni=0`, `$ni=1` e `$ni=2` no [**Ideone**](http://ideone.com/qPDH0y).

**Exemplo 02** <sup>(para quem tem alergia aos parênteses ;))</sup>

```php
$html = ' (nenhum)';

if ($ni >= 1)
    $html = ($ni == 1) ? ' (1 item)' : ' ('.$ni.' itens)';
```

---

## Reutilizar código:

Este tipo de verificações tende a ser utilizado diversas vezes, o que nos leva a reduzir o seu código. Uma abordagem simplicista para redução do código sem que o mesmo perca leitura passa pela criação de uma função:

**Função**

```php
/**
 * Total itens
 *
 * Com base no número recebido, devolve uma indicação
 * humanamente legível sobre o total de itens.
 *
 * @param integer $i Número a analisar.
 * return $string $html HTML pronto a utilizar.
 */
function totalItens ($i=0) {

  $html = ' (nenhum)';

  if ($i >= 1) {

    $html = ($i == 1) ? ' (1 item)' : ' ('.$i.' itens)';
  }

  return $html;
}
```

**Exemplo de utilização**

```
echo totalItens(3);  // saída: (3 itens)
```

Ver exemplo da função no [**Ideone**](http://ideone.com/PZbXOe).