# Como identificar e imprimir quadrados perfeitos com JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Preciso de uma função em JavaScript que imprima no HTML um contador de 1 a 100. Quando o número for um [quadrado perfeito](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrado_perfeito), deve imprimir o texto "quadrado perfeito" depois do número.

Exemplo:

```
1 
2
3
4 QUADRADO PERFEITO
5
6
7
8
9 QUADRADO PERFEITO
10
11
12
13
14
15
16 QUADRADO PERFEITO ...
```

Comment: Como a pergunta não dá mais detalhes, segue uma possibilidade: `function QuadradoPerfeito() { document.write( "1 2 3 4 QUADRADO PERFEITO 5 6 7 8 9 QUADRADO PERFEITO 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 QUADRADO PERFEITO 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 QUADRADO PERFEITO 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 QUADRADO PERFEITO 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 QUADRADO PERFEITO 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 QUADRADO PERFEITO 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 QUADRADO PERFEITO 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100 QUADRADO PERFEITO" ) }` :P

Comment: Não entendi o que vc quis dizer com "quadrado perfeito" :P

Comment: @Ricardo http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrado_perfeito

Answer (score 17):

Notar que seu exemplo está incorreto, pois 1 é quadrado perfeito também.

Segue uma possibilidade, sem muita otimização:

```js
function QuadradoPerfeito( n ) {
  var i;
  var out = '';
  var root;

  for ( i = 1; i <= n; i++ ) {
    root = Math.sqrt( i );
    if ( root == Math.floor( root ) ) {
      out += i + ' QUADRADO PERFEITO<br>';
    } else {
      out += i + '<br>';
    }
  }
  return out;
}

document.body.innerHTML = QuadradoPerfeito( 100 );
```

Explicação resumida:

Ao iterar os números, verificamos se a raiz quadrada do número ( `Math.sqrt` ) é um numero inteiro. Se for, o número é um quadrado perfeito. Para verificar se é um inteiro, basta tirar os decimais usando o `Math.floor` e ver se o número mudou.

### Otimizando a função com [operador condicional](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4907/) e o operador de resto:

```js
function QuadradoPerfeito( n ) {
  var i;
  var out = '';
  var root;

  for ( i = 1; i <= n; i++ )
    out += i + ( Math.sqrt( i ) % 1 === 0 ? ' QUADRADO PERFEITO' : '' ) + '<br>';

  return out;
}

document.body.innerHTML = QuadradoPerfeito( 100 );
```

Explicação resumida:

O [operador condicional](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4907/) substitui o `if` (mais detalhes, basta clicar no link) ao fazer o teste do inteiro.

O operador de resto de divisão (chamado erroneamente de módulo em algumas literaturas, não é a mesma coisa) serve para eliminarmos a necessidade do Math.floor. Se dividirmos a raiz do número por um, pegarmos o resto (que é o que o % faz) e esse resto for zero, significa que `i` um Quadrado Perfeito.

Comment: Muito obrigado. Sou iniciante mas aprendi bastante com sua informação. Apena mudei a impressão. `window.onload = QuadradoPerfeito; document.write (QuadradoPerfeito( 100 ));`

Comment: Nada como um `===` para ajudar a optimizar grandes loops :) +1

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento na falta de prática em JS, me ficou aquela coisa na cabeça de ter certeza que não ia comparar int com float, etc... Fiquei na dúvida se ia de == só :P

Comment: Na verdade eu estava elogiando o seu segundo código. Ao meu ver parece estar correto, mas em questão de `Math.` também não tenho pratica, porém ainda sim parabéns :)

Comment: Funcionar eu sei que funciona, mas me confundo à beça com os tipos :) de qq forma, grato!

Answer (score 6):

Sabendo que os quadrados perfeitos se localizam em intervalos bem definidos:

- Q<sub>1</sub> = 0  + 1 = 1
- Q<sub>2</sub> = 1  + 3 = 4
- Q<sub>3</sub> = 4  + 5 = 9
- Q<sub>4</sub> = 9  + 7 = 16
- Q<sub>5</sub> = 16 + 9 = 25

Simplificando:

- Q<sub>1</sub> = 1
- Q<sub>n</sub> = Q<sub>n-1</sub> + 2n - 1

Podemos imprimir a sequência, **sem depender de `sqrt`**, o que faz desta a forma mais rápida (só que não... [nem sempre é assim](http://jsperf.com/loop-vs-math-sqrt/3)) de processar tal sequência:

```js
function QuadradoPerfeito(n) {
  var out = '';
  var x = 1;
  for (var i = 3; ; i += 2)
  for (var j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    if (x > n) return out;
    out += x + (j == 0 ? ' QUADRADO PERFEITO' : '') + '<br>';
    x++;
  }
}

document.body.innerHTML = QuadradoPerfeito(100);
```

### Mas dois laços aninhados... não é mais lento?

Apesar de ter dois loops aninhados, a quantidade total de cálculos feitos é linear, pois a condição de saída está sobre a variável `x`, que é incrementada em cada passagem.

Além disso, o browser é capaz de otimizar esses laços aninhados de tal forma,
que mesmo refazendo o código com um único laço, o resultado ainda fica mais lento,
entretanto fica bem mais fácil de entender a lógica.

Ai vai uma simulação do que acontece ao chamar o método com `n=20`:

```
i=3:
  j=0: x=1 // QUADRADO PERFEITO
  j=1: x=2
  j=2: x=3
i=5:
  j=0: x=4 // QUADRADO PERFEITO
  j=1: x=5
  j=2: x=6
  j=3: x=7
  j=4: x=8
i=7:
  j=0; x=9 // QUADRADO PERFEITO
  j=1; x=10
  j=2; x=11
  j=3; x=12
  j=4; x=13
  j=5; x=14
  j=6; x=15
i=9:
  j=0; x=16 // QUADRADO PERFEITO
  j=1; x=17
  j=2; x=18
  j=3; x=19
  j=4; x=20
```

### Versão com um único loop, cedida pelo @Bacco

Baseado nos comentários sobre quantidade de loops, @Bacco fez uma versão que tem exatamente a mesma lógica, mas num laço só.

Mas atenção: este laço único não é melhor em termos de performance do que os laços duplos apresentados no início desta resposta! Essa versão serve para ajudar o pessoal com menos experiência a visualizar a lógica.

```
function QuadradoPerfeito(n) {
  var out = '';
  var x = 1;
  var s = 1;
  var i;

  for ( i = 1; i <= n ; i++ ) {
    out += i;
    if ( i == x ) {
      out += ' QUADRADO PERFEITO';
      x = i + (s += 2 );
    }
    out += ' <br>';
  }
  return out;
}

document.body.innerHTML = QuadradoPerfeito(100);
```

Comment: Parece um bom código, mas me diga, por que dois loops seriam melhores do que `Math.sqrt`? Como você tem certeza que `Math.sqrt` é mais lento? Você fez algum teste unitário? :)

Comment: O que importa não é a quantidade de loops aninhados, mas sim o total de passagens que esses loops fazem. Veja que o segundo loop está condicionado ao primeiro. Além disso, a condição de retorno está sobre a variável `x`, que é incrementada no loop mais interno, portanto o total de passagens feitas será exatamente o mesmo valor de `n`.

Comment: Só disse isto para não ficar algo soando como opinião, com "100" realmente o seu exemplo é mais rápido (porém apenas 3% conforme meu teste), aparentemente o seu foi um pouco mais rápido na maioria dos motores EcmaScript: jsperf.com/loop-vs-math-sqrt

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Dei uma olhada lá no jsperf... aqui roda mais rápido algumas vezes outras não... mas na maioria das vezes a versão com sqrt é mais lenta. O mais estranho é que eu fiz uma versão com um loop só, e essa versão ficou a mais lenta de todas aqui: http://jsperf.com/loop-vs-math-sqrt/3

Comment: O motor V8 de EcmaScript deve ter uma estrutura de cache ou "previsão", portanto este deve ser o motivo de resultados diferentes em certas situações, como também pode ser um travamento por executar simultaneamente vários eventos.

Comment: Com tantos motores JavaScript fica realmente difícil falar em "mais rápido"... fica ai como alternativa então.

Comment: @Bacco editei a resposta incluindo o laço único, com o devido crédito... assim as resposta ficam mais organizadas. Valeu ai pela complementação.

Answer (score -2):

```
window.onload = Quadradoperfeito

function Quadradoperfeito {

var numero;
var calculo;

for (numero=1; numero<=100; numero++)
{

calculo = Math.sqrt( numero );

if ( calculo == Math.floor( calculo ) )
{
document.write( numero + ' QUADRADO PERFEITO<br>');
}
 else 
{
document.write(numero + '<br>');
  }

}
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela colaboração, parece a mesma resposta do @Bacco, só que não funciona, pode dizer o que tem de diferente? Obrigado :)