# Alterar height com javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Boa Tarde!

Seguinte, tenho uma `div.minhaDiv` com um `height: 580px;` e quero que ao clicar em um `button` o height dessa `div.minhaDiv` aumente para `1600px`.

Quando ela estiver com `height: 1600px` quero que ao clicar no mesmo `button` o height volte para `580px`;

Segue HTML

```
<div class="minhaDiv">
...
</div>
<button onclick="verMais();" class="botao">Ver mais</button>
```

Javascript

```
var altura = document.querySelector(".minhaDiv");
function verMais(){
    if(altura.style.height <= "580px"){
       altura.style.height = "1600px";
       document.querySelector(".botao").innerHTML = "Ver menos";
    }else{
        altura.style.height = "580px";
        document.querySelector(".botao").innerHTML = "Ver mais";
    }
}
```

Alguem sabe me dizer onde estou errando?
Muito obrigado pessoal, e com certeza é algo muito basico, estou aprendendo javascript, valeu!

Answer (score 1):

Seu erro está apenas nesta linha:

```
if(altura.style.height <= "580px"){
```

Em vez de comparar se é **menor ou igual**, compare se é **igual**:

```
if(altura.style.height == "580px"){
```

```js
var altura = document.querySelector(".minhaDiv");
function verMais(){
   if(altura.style.height == "580px"){
       altura.style.height = "1600px";
       document.querySelector(".botao").innerHTML = "Ver menos";
    }else{
        altura.style.height = "580px";
        document.querySelector(".botao").innerHTML = "Ver mais";
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="minhaDiv" style="display: block; background: red; height: 580px;">
 teste
</div>
<button onclick="verMais();" class="botao">Ver mais</button>
```

> Você deve comparar strings se uma é igual ou diferente da outra, e não menor ou maior.

Answer (score 0):

Parece-me que deves usar uma classe de CSS com essa altura de 1600px e depois usas `.classList.toggle()` para automáticamente adicionar e remover essa classe.

Para mudar o texto do botão podes verificar se o elemento tem a classe com `altura.classList.contains('aumentada')` e aí podes fazer uma [condição ternária](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4908/129) para dar o texto que deve ter.

Seria algo assim:

```
var altura = document.querySelector(".minhaDiv");
var button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click', function(){
    altura.classList.toggle('aumentada');
    button.innerHTML = altura.classList.contains('aumentada') ? 'ver menos' : 'ver mais';
});
```

e o CSS:

```
.minhaDiv {
    height: 580px;
    transition: height .5s; /* opcional, cria uma animação */
}

.aumentada {
    height: 1600px;
}
```

#### Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/a7rp0q46/

Answer (score 0):

Aqui tem uma maneira de fazer isso usando jQuery:

```
$('.botao').on('click', function() {
 var el = $('.minhaDiv');
    if (el.height() != 1600) {
        el.height(1600);
        $(this).text('Ver menos');
    } else {
        el.height(580);
        $(this).text('Ver mais');
    }
 });
<button class="botao">Ver mais</button>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js">
</script>
```

Aqui ele funcionando: **http://jsfiddle.net/ub33vuLg/1/**

E esta uma versão mais animada: **http://jsfiddle.net/ub33vuLg/2/**