# Como pegar os valores das ultima 4 colunas com Jquery

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces

Tenho um `panelGrid`, e gostaria de saber como pegar os 4 últimos elementos antes de um determinado da mesma linha.

Ou seja, tenho uma linha, e o ultimo elemento vai receber a soma dos quatro anteriores.

Obrigado

Comment: Você tem algum código para postar ? pode exemplificar melhor sua dúvida ? não entendi claramente.

Comment: Eu gostaria de ter pego os 5 ultimos elementos de uma query, fiz usando o seguinte: `$('.columnRight  > label').slice(-5)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando o seletor do jQuery junto a função de array `forEach` você consegue selecionar os 5 últimos elementos do conjunto, somar os 4 primeiros e quando chegar no último atribuir o valor total da soma.

Segue exemplo:

```js
var total = 0;
Array.prototype.forEach.call($('.columnRight > label'), function(val, idx, arr) {
  if(arr.length > 5 ? idx > arr.length - 6 ? true : false : false) {
    if(idx == arr.length - 1) {
      val.textContent = total;
    } else {
      total = total + parseInt(val.textContent);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="columnRight">
  <label>1</label>
  <label>2</label>
  <label>3</label>
  <label>4</label>
  <label>5</label>
  <label>6</label>
  <label></label>
</div>
```

Nesta linha `if(arr.length > 5 ? idx > arr.length - 6 ? true : false : false) {` utilizei uma operação ternária para evitar um aninhamento de `if`'s, basicamente ele verifica se a quantidade de elementos no array é maior que 5, se for verifica se o index atual é maior que a quantidade de elementos no array menos seis, se sim faz o resto da operação. Entenda mais sobre operações ternárias [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4907/como-funciona-este-if-else-com-e/4908#4908).

O último `label` possui a soma dos valores dos 4 anteriores a ele.

> Veja funcionando no [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/devgaspa/jgz3b2ur/).

Referência: [MDN - forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Comment: Deu certo, eu já tinha conseguido com uma função menor mas menos elaborada que a sua, mas a sua funciona melhor lembrando que no meu caso o numero é uma `String` e tinha junto o `R$` e precisei tratar.