# Qual a forma correta de retornar um valor do "switch"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, switch

Como é a forma correta de retornar o valor do `switch`?

HTML:

```html
<h3 id="txtOcorrenciaStatus">Status</h3>
```

Javascript:

```javascript
switch(ocoStatus) {
   case C:
      $("#OcorrenciaStatus").html("Concluído");
      break;
   case A:
      $("#OcorrenciaStatus").html("Aberto");
      break;
}
```

Comment: Se forem duas opçoes só, não faz sentido usar switch. Uma linha só com ? : (ternário) bastaria: `$("#OcorrenciaStatus").html( ocoStatus == 'C'?"Concluído":"Aberto");`

Comment: @Bacco Obrigado.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para o caso específico do seu código, com duas opçoes apenas, não faria muito sentido usar switch. Uma linha só com `? :` (ternário) bastaria:

```
$("#OcorrenciaStatus").html( ocoStatus == 'C'? "Concluído" : "Aberto" );
```

Como já mostrado em [outra resposta aqui no SOpt](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4907), o ternário tem esta estrutura:

```
condição/valor verdadeiro ou falso ? retorno se verdadeiro : retorno se falso
```

Só para constar, seu código pode ser escrito assim também:

```
if ( ocoStatus == 'C' ) {
   $("#OcorrenciaStatus").html("Concluído");
} else if ( ocoStatus == 'A' ) {
   $("#OcorrenciaStatus").html("Aberto");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Bem, o `switch` possui essa estrutura:

```
switch (expression) {
  case value1:
    //Instruções executadas quando o resultado da expressão for igual á value1
    break;
  case value2:
    //Instruções executadas quando o resultado da expressão for igual á value2
    break;
  ...
  case valueN:
    //Instruções executadas quando o resultado da expressão for igual á valueN
    break;
  default:
    //Instruções executadas quando o valor da expressão é diferente de todos os cases
    break;
}
```

A *key-word* `break` faz com que, após a execução do código dentro de um dos possíveis resultados da condição, haja um salto para fora do `switch`.

Esse  método é usado para uma expressão que possa resultar em vários casos, como, por exemplo, a escolha de um dia da semana. É mais uma questão semântica. Já que vários `ifs`, `elses` podem deixar o código um tanto ilegível.

Há também a possibilidade de determinar uma única instrução para mais de um caso, por exemplo:

```
switch (expression) {
  case value1:
  case value2:
  case value3:
    //Instruções executadas quando o resultado da expressão for igual á value 1, value 2 ou value 3.
    break;
  ...
  case valueN:
    //Instruções executadas quando o resultado da expressão for igual á valueN
    break;
  default:
    //Instruções executadas quando o valor da expressão é diferente de todos os cases
    break;
}
```

Vale lembrar que o `default` é opcional, entretanto, é interessante, por mais uma vez uma questão de semântica, usá-lo.

O @Bacco deixou uma resposta, no seu comentário, bem consistente para o seu caso. Mas, resolvi deixar essa resposta apenas como algo mais esclarecedor.