# Resultado de cáculo em JS retornando R$ NaN

Tags: javascript

Fiz um formulário de cálculo usando JS. A questão é que tem campos que são obrigatórios, onde o usuário é obrigado a escolher uma opção com valor, pois o cálculo é combinado. Quando ele não escolhe a opção obrigatório retorna `NaN`.

Como posso corrigir isso?

Esse é meu código:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    String.prototype.formatMoney = function() {
        var v = this;

        if (v.indexOf('.') === -1) {
            v = v.replace(/([\d]+)/, "$1,00");
        }

        v = v.replace(/([\d]+)\.([\d]{1})$/, "$1,$20");
        v = v.replace(/([\d]+)\.([\d]{2})$/, "$1,$2");
        v = v.replace(/([\d]+)([\d]{3}),([\d]{2})$/, "$1.$2,$3");

        return v;
    };

    function id(el) {
        return document.getElementById(el);
    }

    function getMoney(el) {
        var money = id(el).value.replace(',', '.');
        return parseFloat(money) * 100;
    }

    function soma() {
        var total = getMoney('internet') + getMoney('wifi');
        id('campo5').value = 'R$ ' + String(total / 100).formatMoney();
    }

</script>
```

Campo resultado:

```
<input type="text" class="bd-form-input" name="campo5" readonly id="campo5" />
```

Botton:

```
<div>
    <a href="#" onclick="soma()" value="Calcular Plano" title="Clique para calcular seu plano">calcular plano</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesta linha do teu código

```
var money = id( el ).value.replace( ',', '.' );
```

tens de criar um *fallback* para quando esse input estiver vazio. Isto porque mais à frente vais utilizar `parseFloat()` e quando money estiver vazio isso dá `NaN`. Corrige para:

```
var money = id( el ).value.replace( ',', '.' ) || 0;
```

Depois, na soma final, para nõ dar valor senão quando o valor de `internet` estiver setado podes fazer assim:

```
function soma() {
    var inet = getMoney('internet');
    var total = inet + getMoney('wifi');
    id('campo5').value = inet ? 'R$ ' + String(total / 100).formatMoney() : '';
}
```

Assim com esse ternário na ultima linha ele verifica se o `inet` tem valor, se não salta para depois do `:` e usa uma string vazia `''`.

O [ternário funciona assim](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4908/129):

```
condição ? caso verdadeiro : caso falso;
```

Então se tiveres mais condições podes fazer usando essa lógica

```
id('campo5').value = internet && telefone ? 'R$ ' [etc...] : '';
```

Answer (score 0):

Adicione o operator `||` (or) nessa linha (onde você chama o `parseFloat`):

```
return parseFloat( money )*100;
```

Exemplo:

```
return (parseFloat( money ) || 0) * 100;
```

Agora, se o `parseFloat( money )` retornar `NaN`, vai ser retornado um `0` no lugar.

Comment: a senteça `(parseFloat( money ) || 0)` não faz com q itens menores que `0` se torner `0` (por exemplo `-1` continuará sendo `-1`), apenas valores que possam ser convertidos para `false`, você pode ver melhor em https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation

Comment: @LuanCastro Obrigado.