# Como listar uma resposta da GraphApi com o React?

Tags: lista, facebook, react

Estou há dias tentando criar uma simples lista com os nomes dos eventos que recebo de uma requisição pra GraphApi do Facebook. O objeto que eu recebo é o seguinte:
[image: Response]

Como faço uma lista apenas com os nomes dos eventos? por exemplo:
John Mayer....
Popload....
Tormentos...
...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dentro desse `events` tens uma array de objetos, então no teu render podes ter algo assim:

(assumindo que `events` está no `state` como `this.state.events`)

```js
render() {
  const events = this.state.events;
  const eventsItems = events ? events.data.map(
    event => (<p key={event.id}>{event.description}</p>)
  ) : [];
  return (
     <div>
        {events}
     </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Perfeito. Agora funcionou. Ainda não entendi muito bem essa condicional. Isso é o ES6? Como ficaria na syntax antiga?

Comment: @JucaEsmanhoto dá uma olhada aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4908/129 (isso é anterior a ES6)

Comment: Ótimo! Muito Obrigado!