# Alguém sabe me dizer por que o "#obj" não se movimenta?

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos

```
/*ignorem o que tem a cima, o importante é na 'areaTestes', onde a bola não se desloca para baixo, sendo que eu estou chamando a função a cada 1s, ela não deveria descer?*/
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>TESTES</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


</head>
<body>
    <style type="text/css">
    body{
        background-color: #00bbff;
    }
    /*predefinido pra uso sla*/
    .toast{
        background-color: black;
        border-radius: 10px;
        color: white;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    div{
        background-color: coral;
    }
    /*TESTES DE ENTENDIMENTO DIV E SPAN COM DISPLAYS*/
    span{
        background-color: dodgerblue;
    }
    div:nth-child(2), span{
        height: 30px;
        width: 100px;
    }
    /*TESTES POSITIONS COM %*/
    .fora{
        position: relative;
        padding: 20px;
        width: 400px;
        height: 400px;
        background-color: chartreuse;
    }
    .dentro{
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px;
        position: absolute; /*conteudo + padding (com o relative no pai), sem o relative ele pega a partir do viewport*/
    }
    .areaTestes{
        position: relative;
        width: 1200px;
        height: 700px;
        background-color: darkcyan;
        border: 3px solid black;
        margin: 30px 0;
    }
    .obj{
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: green;
        border: 2px double aqua;
        border-radius: 50px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
    }
    </style>
    <center>
    <div id="toast" class="toast">
        This is a TOAST!!
        </div>

        <div>Div Teste</div>
        <span>Span Teste</span>

        <div class="fora">
            <div class="dentro"></div>
        </div>


        <div class="areaTestes">
            <div class="obj" id="objID"></div>
        </div>
    </center>

    <script>
           var obj = document.getElementById('objID')

           var getY = () => parseInt(obj.style.top.split('px')[0])
            var setY = y => obj.style.top = `${y}px`

           function deslocamento(top) {
            setY(getY() - top)
           }
           setInterval(() => {
            deslocamento(10)
           }, 1000)
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Primeira coisa, as variáveis que você está tentando utilizar dentro das funções estão sendo declaradas fora do escopo da função e não são globais, então a função não consegue enxergá-las.

Answer (score 1):

Sua função `getY` está retornando `NAN` ao ser executada da primeira vez, pelo top não ter um valor definido.

Pode-se usar um [operador condicional ternário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4907/como-funciona-este-if-else-com-e/4916#4916) para retornar um valor caso o top não tenha um valor, nesse exemplo eu coloquei para retornar zero.

```
var getY = () => parseInt(obj.style.top != '' ? obj.style.top.split('px')[0] : 0)
```

Comment: Obrigado!! Eu fiz o teste e realmente estava retornando NaN, mas como tinha definido ja o "0" no css, achei que retornaria 0, mas pelo visto não