# Diferença entre If com e sem chaves

Tags: javascript, node.js

Estava acompanhando alguns cursos de NodeJS, e percebi que em muitos dos casos é utilizado um `if` mais básico do tradicional (venho do C#).

Minha dúvida é a seguinte: Existe alguma diferença além da síntaxe entre eles? Performance? Qual eu devo utilizar?

Segue exemplo abaixo:

```
    if (typeof nome !== "undefined"){
        usuario.nome = nome;
    }
    if (typeof email !== "undefined"){
        usuario.email = email;
    }
    if (typeof password !== "undefined"){
        usuario.setSenha(password);
    }

    if (typeof nome !== "undefined") usuario.nome = nome;
    if (typeof email !== "undefined") usuario.email = email;
    if (typeof password !== "undefined") usuario.setSenha(password);
```

E no caso de:

`link: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "https://DOMINIO.COM" : "http://localhost:8000"`

Comment: @LuizFelipe Obrigado! Mas e em questão de performance, muda alguma coisa?

Comment: Tenho quase certeza que não há ganho ou perda de performance, até porque imagino que essa nem seja a principal causa de eventuais problemas desse tipo. Na maioria dos casos, esse tipo de problema está ligado à implementação feita pelo programador...

Comment: E quanto a sua edição, também é duplicata: [Como funciona este if/else com “?” e “:”?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4907/como-funciona-este-if-else-com-e). Por favor, pesquise no site antes de abrir uma pergunta.