# É possível condicionar um operador += em um ternário?

Tags: javascript, lógica, operadores

Eu tenho um objeto vazio:

```
obj = {}
```

Tento verificar se existe uma chave `op1` nesse objeto. Se não houver eu quero adicionar a chave e um valor qualquer, ficando assim:

```
obj = { op1: 10 } // O valor 10 é hipotético.
```

Caso a chave `op1` exista no objeto `obj` eu quero somar um valor qualquer ao valor já existente nessa chave. Por exemplo, se:

```
obj = { op1: 10 }
```

E eu venha com um valor 15, ficaria:

```
obj = { op1: 25 }
```

Até aqui tudo bem. Tenho um código que faz essa verificação e soma utilizando `if...else`:

```
var valor = 15;
if(obj["op1"]){
   obj["op1"] += valor;
}else{
   obj["op1"] = valor;
}
```

Se a chave `op1` já existir no `obj`, eu apenas atualizo o valor, caso não exista, eu crio a chave `op1` com o valor da variável `valor`.

Minha dúvida é: existe alguma forma de eliminar esse `if...else` utilizando um operador ternário, já que única diferença entre o `if` e o `else` é o operador `+=`? Ou então teria alguma forma de simplificar esse `if...else`?

Comment: Ótima pergunta, passei exatamente por essa situação há poucos dias atrás e acabei criando um código com ```if...else``` como você cita.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Operadores desse tipo, como o `+=`, fazem duas coisas:

- Efetuam uma operação aritmética (no caso, a operação de adição), e:
- Atribuem o resultado da opração de volta à variável.

Para saber mais, consulte a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Addition_assignment).

Desse modo, os dois exemplos a seguir são equivalentes, sendo o segundo considerado um tipo de abreviação do primeiro:

```js
variable = variable + 10;
variable += 10;
```

Portanto, você não pode fazer nenhum tipo de verificação à direita do `+=` para saber se ele é `undefined` ou não, já que o valor à direita será simplesmente o valor a ser usado na operação aritmética.

Você pode usar operadores ternários para fazer isso em somente uma expressão, mas a lógica será a mesma do `if`/`else`. Veja:

```js
const obj = { keyA: 5 };
const value = 10;

const keyA = 'keyA';
obj[keyA] ? obj[keyA] += value : obj[keyA] = value;

const keyB = 'keyB';
obj[keyB] ? obj[keyB] += value : obj[keyB] = value;

console.log(obj);
```

Mas nesse caso creio que não valha a pena, a não ser que você precise que seja só uma única expressão... Só vejo utilidade de você estiver usando a forma curta de *arrow functions*, já que o `if`/`else` acaba sendo bem menos *complicado*. :)

Mas você pode optar por não usar operadores como o `+=`. Nesse caso, você poderá fazer algo assim:

```js
const obj = { keyA: 5 };
const value = 10;

const keyA = 'keyA';
obj[keyA] = (obj[keyA] || 0) + value;

const keyB = 'keyB';
obj[keyB] = (obj[keyB] || 0) + value;

console.log(obj);
```

Se for para fazer em uma só expressão, eu *pessoalmente* optaria por essa última opção.

Em suma, esses são só mais alguns exemplos do fato de que existem infinitas formas de atingir a uma mesmo objetivo na programação. :)

Comment: Concordo, sua última sugestão é mais legível que fazer atribuição no miolo do condicional ternário – a propósito, eu comento sobre a legibilidade desse operador em casos assim [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4916/74).

Comment: @bfavaretto, na sua resposta, a parte do "controle de fluxo" explica exatamente o porquê de que eu [pessoalmente] não usaria um ternário no primeiro exemplo. Apesar de não estar errado, não vejo muito sentido naquele caso (a não ser que uma única expressão seja necessária – o que raramente é o caso). :]

Comment: Olhei a primeira sugestão eu assustei, achei alguém tinha roubado a sua conta. Só me tranquilizei após ler a ultima opção.

Comment: O último código ficou bem elegante e simples.

Answer (score -6):

Na verdade, basta só colocar o `obj["op1"] += valor;`
caso ele não exista, ele não tem valor e vai assumir o valor só da variavel.

Comment: Fiz esse teste e gerou um ```undefinedTeste``` com string e ```NaN``` com números... :(

Comment: O resultado disso será `NaN`, já que você está tentando somar `undefined` com `valor`, que é um número.