# Verificar quantas vezes um número aparece no array

Tags: javascript, array

Eu tenho um array com os seguintes valores:

```
let arrey = ["1","1","1","2","2","2"];
```

Como é possível verificar quantas vezes o número 1 aparece e quantas vezes o número 2 aparece, por exemplo, esses números são alterados a cada vez que eu executar o meu programa, preciso verificar quantas vezes o número especificado apareceu no array, ou o retorno deve ser outro outro como esse:

```
let arrey2 = [ 

  {
     "numero": 1,
     "quantidade": 3
  },
  {
     "numero": 2,
     "quantidade": 3
  }
]
```

O código:

```
function itemCount(arrey){
    let valor = arrey[0];
    let length = arrey.length
    let index = []
    let contador =  0
    let x = 0
    let bol;
    while(x < length){
        for(let i = 0; i < arrey.length; i++){
            if(arrey[x] === valor){
                console.log(arrey[x])
                contador += 1
            }
        }
        
        let obj = {
            "produto_id": arrey[x],
            "quantidade": contador
        }
        if(index.length > 0){
            index.forEach(itemArrey => {
               if(itemArrey.produto_id === obj.produto_id){
                   bol = false;
               }else{
                   bol = true;
               }
            });
            if(bol == true){
                index.push(obj);
            }
        }else if(index.length == 0){
            index.push(obj);
        }
        x++
    }
    return index;
}
```

Passando o seguinte array como entrada:

```
let arrey = ['1','1','2','2','2'];
intemCount(arrey);
```

A saída desse meu código é a seguinte:

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0: {produto_id: "1", quantidade: 5}
1: {produto_id: "2", quantidade: 10}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apesar de que é possível fazer o seu código funcionar, acho que vale mais a pena compreender que existem outras formas (mais simples e mais eficientes) de se fazer o que você precisa.

Se você sempre estiver trabalhando com um array de primitivos (números, strings, etc), você pode criar um objeto seguido da "contagem" de vezes em que ele aparece (por padrão, zero). Assim, você só precisará iterar uma vez sobre o array.

Algo assim:

```js
function countItems(arr) {
  const countMap = Object.create(null);

  for (const element of arr) {
    if (!countMap[element]) {
      // Se ainda não existir elemento, definimos como um, já que
      // estamos na primeira ocorrência.
      countMap[element] = 1;
    } else {
      // Caso contrário, incrementamos um no número atual.
      countMap[element] += 1;
    }
  }
  
  return countMap;
}

const arr = ['1', '1', '2', '2', '2'];
console.log(countItems(arr));
```

Você pode ainda [simplificar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/452540/69296) o código acima ao utilizar operadores de [curto-circuito](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/274110/69296):

```js
function countItems(arr) {
  const countMap = Object.create(null);

  for (const element of arr) {
    // Basicamente, estamos dizendo: atribua à `countMap[element]` o valor
    // atual (ou zero, caso não existir) somado ao número 1.
    countMap[element] = (countMap[element] || 0) + 1;
  }
  
  return countMap;
}

const arr = ['1', '1', '2', '2', '2'];
console.log(countItems(arr));
```

E para transformar o `countMap` no array de saída que você espera, uma opção é utilizar o [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) em conjunto do [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
function countItems(arr) {
  const countMap = Object.create(null);

  for (const element of arr) {
    // Basicamente, estamos dizendo: atribua à `countMap[element]` o valor
    // atual (ou zero, caso não existir) somado ao número 1.
    countMap[element] = (countMap[element] || 0) + 1;
  }

  return Object.entries(countMap).map(([value, count]) => ({
    numero: value,
    quantidade: count
  }));
}

const arr = ['1', '1', '2', '2', '2'];
console.log(countItems(arr));
```

O problema é que essa "tradução" adiciona um leve custo (imperceptível no seu caso, já que penso que você trabalhará com poucos itens), uma vez que uma outra repetição terá que ser feita, para o número de propriedades de `countMap`, isto é, o número de itens únicos do array.

Eu pessoalmente prefiro simplesmente retornar o objeto `countMap`. Nada te impede de usar o `Object.entries` em simplesmente outra parte do código.

Comment: Nossa!simplesmente incrível!
Muito obrigado por me dar essa aula, estava complicando demais as coisas sendo que não era esse bicho de sete cabeças que eu estava pensando. Além de me dar uma aula me passou conhecimentos novos em JS. Muito obrigado!!!!!

Answer (score 6):

Uma possibilidade é utilizar o método [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) que executa uma função redutora para cada elemento do [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), resultando em um único valor de retorno. No seu caso `reduce()` pode ser usado para montar e retornar um objeto que cada uma de suas propriedade sejam nomeadas pelos elementos distintos do `Array` de entrada e valor de cada uma dessas propriedades sejam um sub-objeto cujos as propriedades seriam `"número"` e `"quantidade"`.

```js
let arr = ["1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "4", "4"];


let resultado = arr.reduce((acc, val) => {
  if (!acc[val]) acc[val] = {
    "número": val,
    "quantidade": 1
  };
  else acc[val]["quantidade"]++;
  return acc;
}, {});


console.log(resultado);
```

Para remover os pseudo-indices basta para entrada do resultado utilizar o método [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) e retornar o seu valor, para obter uma a uma as entrada do resultado use o método [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) que retorna uma array dos pares *[chave, valor]* enumeráveis de um dado objeto, índice 0 é a chave índice 1 é o valor.

```js
let arr = ["1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "4", "4"];


let resultado = arr.reduce((acc, val) => {
  if (!acc[val]) acc[val] = {
    "número": val,
    "quantidade": 1
  };
  else acc[val]["quantidade"]++;
  return acc;
}, {});


console.log(Object.entries(resultado).map((val) => {
  return val[1];
}));
```

**UPDATE:**

Como sugerido pelo Luiz Felipe o uso do método [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) pode simplificar em muito o código. `Object.values()` retorna um array com os valores das propriedades de um dado objeto

```js
let arr = ["1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "4", "4"];


let resultado = arr.reduce((acc, val) => {
  if (!acc[val]) acc[val] = {
    "número": val,
    "quantidade": 1
  };
  else acc[val]["quantidade"]++;
  return acc;
}, {});


console.log(Object.values(resultado));
```

Comment: Boa resposta, Augusto! Só no final que poderia trocar o `Object.entries` pelo `Object.values` para ficar melhor ainda! :-)

Comment: @LuizFelipe, fiz uma edição contendo sua sugestão. Achei muito boa, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 4):

A expressão `counts[x] || 0` retorna o valor de `counts[x]` se estiver definida, caso contrário `0`.
Em seguida, basta adicionar um e configurá-lo novamente no objeto e a contagem é concluída.

```js
let arrey = ["1","1","2","2","2"];
var counts = {};
arrey.forEach(function(x) { counts[x] = (counts[x] || 0)+1; });

console.log(counts);
```

[Aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395257/how-to-count-duplicate-value-in-an-array-in-javascript) tem esse que postei e muito mais