# Como posso contar quantas vezes um número aparece em multiplos arrays?

Tags: javascript, node.js, parser

Estou tentando fazer uma aplicação na qual eu entro um arquivo txt com os resultados das ultimas mega Sena e faço o parse linha por linha. Meu objetivo é ver quantas vezes determinado número apareceu desde o começo da mega Sena. Estou utilizando Javascript rodando em Node.Js

Por enquanto consegui chegar no seguinte:

```
2324 (05/12/2020) 02 16 19 31 43 60
2323 (02/12/2020) 20 27 35 39 50 59
2322 (28/11/2020) 02 05 10 29 34 41

\/

[ '02', '16', '19', '31', '43', '60' ],
[ '20', '27', '35', '39', '50', '59' ],
[ '02', '05', '10', '29', '34', '41' ],
```

Porém não sei como posso ler cada elemento e incrementar um contador relativo a aquele elemento..

Esse é meu código até o momento:

```
let fs = require('fs')
let input = fs.readFileSync('./input.txt', 'utf-8')
let lines = input.split('\n')
let emptyLinesRemoved = lines.filter((element) => element.length > 0)
let onlyNumbers = emptyLinesRemoved.map((element) =>
  element.split(' ').slice(2)
)
console.log(onlyNumbers)
```

Alguma sugestão? Agradeço desde já :)

Comment: Se o input é parecido pra todos os arrays, o que você acha de juntá-los todos em um array e contar a ocorrência de cada número uma única vez?

Pensei nisso, ou então você fazer um array de arrays e percorrê-lo contando as ocorrências

Comment: Tinha pensado nisso também! Juntar todos os arrays usando concat... Mas estou um pouco em dúvida de como implementar

Comment: Esta outra pergunta o ajuda? Não é exatamente o mesmo problema, porém parecida: [Verificar quantas vezes um número aparece no array](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/459413/692960)

Comment: Acho que consegui! Essa pergunta era exatamente o que eu precisava! Muito obrigado Luiz Felipe. Vou editar a solução

Comment: Não consigo colocar uma resposta nova, mas o seguinte trecho fez funcionar da maneira esperada:
let count = {}
onlyNumbers.forEach((array) => {
  array.forEach((element) => {
    if (!count[element]) count[element] = 1
    else count[element] += 1
  })
})

Answer (score 0):

Partindo do princípio que onlyNumbers já é um array de arrays, uma vez que o método Map retorna uma array, acho que você pode fazer o seguinte:

primeiramente, pra concatenar os arrays:

```js
var mergedArray = [].concat.apply([], onlyNumbers);
```

depois, pra facilitar a contagem vamos ordenar o array resultante:

```js
mergedArray.sort();
```

pra finalizar, você pode contar as ocorrências de cada número assim:

```js
var occurrences = {};

for (var i = 0; i < mergedArray.length; i++) {
  var num = mergedArray[i];
  occurrences[num] = occurrences[num] ? occurrences[num] + 1 : 1;
}
```

Comment: Essa solução faz com que todos os números fiquem com 1 em occurences

Comment: @CayoEduardo desculpe, havia um erro no código, já corrigi.