# Minha função retorna true or false. Fiz o código, mas acho que poderia ser mais curtinha com métodos nativos js

Tags: javascript

Minha função retorna `true` or `false`, fiz o código, mas acho que poderia ser mais curtinha com métodos nativos javascript:

```
function authorUnique() {
 return books.every((book) => {
    for (let i in book) {
      for (let j in book) {
        if (Object.values(book.author.birthYear)[i] ===
            Object.values(book.author.birthYear)[j]
        ) {
          false;
        } else {
          true;
        }
      }
    }
  })
```

Comment: O seu titulo está muito mau elaborado, e a seu código realmente muito mau escrito, fazendo duas interação para comparar valores, o que você realmente deseja fazer e o que é books você quando criar pergunta aqui precisa detalhar para que não tenhamos duvidas, ou seja, gerou somente duvida a sua pergunta.

Comment: Agradeço o retorno, e compreendo a necessidade de melhorar o titulo da pergunta. Quero evitar esses loops, quero verificar se no array de objetos tenho 2 autores com a mesma idade. Se, puder me ajudar, eu agradeço imensamente.

Answer (score 2):

O [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) não é o mais ideal neste caso, ele é mais indicado quando você quer testar se *todos* os elementos de um array validam algum predicado.

Nesse caso um laço `for` com um mapa para saber quantos anos já foram verificados já resolveria o seu problema:

```js
function authorUniqueByBirthYear(books) {
  const map = Object.create(null);

  for (const { author } of books) {
    if (map[author.birthYear]) {
      map[author.birthYear]++;
    } else {
      map[author.birthYear] = 1;
    }

    if (map[author.birthYear] === 2) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}

console.log(authorUniqueByBirthYear([
  { author: { birthYear: 1 } },
  { author: { birthYear: 2 } },
  { author: { birthYear: 2 } },
  { author: { birthYear: 3 } }
])); // false

console.log(authorUniqueByBirthYear([
  { author: { birthYear: 1 } },
  { author: { birthYear: 2 } },
  { author: { birthYear: 3 } }
])); // true
```

A lógica é simples:

1. Iniciar `map` como um objeto vazio (utilizamos `Object.create(null)` para isso).
2. Para cada autor da lista de livros passada como parâmetro, faça:

   1. Se, em `map`, o ano de nascimento do autor já tiver sido contabilizado em `map` por alguma iteração anterior, soma-se `1` à contagem correspondente ao ano de aniversário da iteração atual.
   2. Caso contrário, iniciamos, no `map`, o valor `1` para o ano do nascimento do autor da iteração atual.
   3. Se o ano de nascimento da iteração atual tem um valor igual a `2` em `map`, retorne `false`.
3. Retornar `true` (indica que todos os autores são únicos pela data de nascimento).

Temos, então, um código com complexidade [O(n)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56836/69296), no pior dos casos.

---

Tem como tornar a verificação `2.1` e `2.2` um pouco mais compacta no código:

```js
function authorUniqueByBirthYear(books) {
  const map = Object.create(null);

  for (const { author } of books) {
    map[author.birthYear] = (map[author.birthYear] || 0) + 1;

    if (map[author.birthYear] === 2) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}

console.log(authorUniqueByBirthYear([
  { author: { birthYear: 1 } },
  { author: { birthYear: 2 } },
  { author: { birthYear: 2 } },
  { author: { birthYear: 3 } }
])); // false

console.log(authorUniqueByBirthYear([
  { author: { birthYear: 1 } },
  { author: { birthYear: 2 } },
  { author: { birthYear: 3 } }
])); // true
```

Veja [mais sobre o operador OR (`||`) nesse tipo de caso de uso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/452540/69296).

Em suma, na maioria das vezes procuramos utilizar métodos "mais sofisticados" (como o `every`), sendo que um bom e velho `for` já resolve bem mais facilmente. :)