# Como contar ocorrências de um valor dentro de um array?

Tags: javascript, array

Como pegar a quantidade de vezes que uma string se repete dentro de um array?

Ex:

```js
var teste = ["oi", "tudo", "bem", "oi"];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a função `filter` para gerar um novo array com todos os elementos que você deseja, e então chame a propriedade `length` deste novo array.

```js
var teste = [ "oi","tudo","bem","oi"];
var quantidadeElementos = teste.filter(x => x === "oi").length;
console.log("O array possui " + quantidadeElementos + " elementos iguais a 'oi'")
```

Documentação:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 5):

Só pra complementar a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/484146/112052): usar `filter` de fato funciona, mas deve-se lembrar que [`filter` retorna outro array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Return_value) com os resultados da filtragem.

Se você quer saber **apenas** a quantidade de elementos e nada mais, será que vale a pena criar um outro array, só para pegar o tamanho? Não seria melhor ter um contador?

```js
var teste = ["oi", "tudo", "bem", "oi"];
var qtd = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < teste.length; i++) {
    if (teste[i] === "oi") qtd++;
}
console.log(qtd); // 2
```

Ou, usando [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of):

```js
var teste = ["oi", "tudo", "bem", "oi"];
var qtd = 0;
for (var s of teste) {
    if (s === "oi") qtd++;
}
console.log(qtd); // 2
```

> "*Ah, mas `filter` faz tudo em uma linha.*"

E daí? [Código "menor" não é necessariamente "melhor"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/400495/112052). Por exemplo, [`filter` é mais lento que os *loops*](https://jsbench.me/ubki058ti3/2). Claro que para poucos arrays pequenos a diferença será insignificante e talvez não passe de micro-otimização, e sempre é bom testar com casos reais para saber se de fato é um problema. Mas de qualquer forma, é interessante saber os detalhes de tudo que você usa e escolher com critérios mais objetivos do que "*é mais curto*". Muitas vezes um código menor pode esconder alguma complexidade extra (como o fato de ter que chamar várias vezes uma função - sim, o parâmetro que você passa para `filter` é uma função - e ainda criar outro array para guardar os resultados).

Não que seja um grande erro usar `filter`, só quis aprofundar um pouco a discussão para mostrar que tem vezes em que fazer as coisas "na mão" não é uma alternativa tão ruim assim.

---

Outro motivo para eu não preferir `filter` nesse caso específico: para que gerar um array em que todos os elementos são iguais?

```js
var teste = ["oi", "tudo", "bem", "oi"];
console.log(teste.filter(x => x === "oi")); // [ "oi", "oi" ]
```

`filter` é interessante se o critério pode retornar diferentes elementos. Por exemplo, se fosse "todas as strings que começam com determinada letra", aí pode fazer sentido retornar o array (mas só se você quiser saber **quais** são esses elementos; se quer saber apenas **quantos** são, eu ainda acho um "exagero" criar outro array só para pegar o tamanho).

Answer (score 4):

A pergunta já foi respondida com o uso de `filter` ([aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/484148/100416)) e com uso de `for` ([aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/484168/100416)), ambas são soluções válidas para o problema, porém quero trazer uma outra alternativa, também utilizando um dos métodos do Array, que é o [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

O `reduce` executará uma função dada para cada elemento do Array e acumulará um resultado, sendo que você define o que é esse resultado (pode ser um número, um array, uma string...).

Para a contagem de ocorrências, podemos fazer:

```js
var teste = ["oi", "tudo", "bem", "oi"];
var qtd = teste.reduce((total, valor) => {
  if (valor === "oi") {
    return total + 1;
  }
  return total;
}, 0); // 0 é o "total" inicial

console.log(qtd); // 2
```

Neste caso, o `reduce`, assim como o `for`, não irá criar um novo Array desnecessariamente, diferentemente do `filter`.

Outro ponto de observação é que com o uso do `reduce` você pode armazenar o resultado em uma constante (`const`).

Answer (score 4):

As outras três respostas contam quantas vezes **uma** string se repete dentro de um array, mas e na possibilidade de **várias** strings se repetirem?

Nesse caso você poderia "adaptar" o código das outras respostas e contar um para cada palavra repetida. Mas obviamente isso não seria eficiente, já que teria que percorrer todo o array para cada palavra que fosse necessário verificar.

Um jeito relativamente simples para se resolver esse problema (de forma relativamente eficiente) é utilizar um objeto para servir de contador. Desse modo, contaríamos a ocorrência de **cada** string dentro do array, varrendo-a apenas uma vez.

Veja:

```js
const arr = ['oi', 'oi', 'oi', 'tudo', 'tudo', 'bem', '?'];
console.log(countDuplicates(arr));

function countDuplicates(arr) {
  const map = Object.create(null);
  
  for (const str of arr) {
    if (map[str]) {
      // Se já tiver contabilizado, some `1` ao contador:
      map[str] += 1;
    } else {
      // Caso contrário, iniciamos o contador como `1`:
      map[str] = 1;
    }
  }
  
  return map;
}
```

Mas note que o objeto retornará todos os elementos do array, inclusive aqueles que apareceram somente uma vez. Para resolver isso, pode-se iterar sobre as propriedades do objeto criado e mostrar somente aquelas com valor maior que `1`. Assim:

```js
const arr = ['oi', 'oi', 'oi', 'tudo', 'tudo', 'bem', '?'];
console.log(countDuplicates(arr));

function countDuplicates(arr) {
  // Nosso mapa (objeto vazio sem protótipo):
  const map = Object.create(null);
  
  for (const str of arr) {
    map[str] = (map[str] || 0) + 1;
  }
  
  const repeatedMap = Object.create(null);
  for (const prop in map) {
    if (map[prop] > 1) {
      repeatedMap[prop] = map[prop];
    }
  }
  
  return repeatedMap;
}
```

Note que eu também removi o `if`/`else` do primeiro `for`, abreviando para a expressão `(map[str] || 0) + 1`. [Saiba mais.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/452540/69296)

Answer (score 0):

Segue código em que no array 'queries' estão as palavras a consultar, e no array 'strings' estão as palavras da amostra. A saída é um array com a quantidade de ocorrências de cada palavra do array 'strings'.

```
    strings = ['aba', 'baba', 'aba', 'xzxb'];
    queries = ['aba', 'xzxb', 'ab'];
    let results = [];
    
    let n = strings.length;
    let q = queries.length;
    let cont = 0;

    for (let i=0; i<q; i++){
        for (let j=0; j < n; j++){
            if (queries[i] == strings[j]) {
                cont++
            }
        }
        results.push(cont);
        cont = 0;
    }

    return console.log (results);
}
```