# Calcular soma e subtração em Javascript

Tags: javascript

Sou iniciante em programação e estou começando por Javascript e preciso resolver a seguinte questão que não está apresentando resultado adequando quando realiza a subtração: somar os dois números se tiver o sinal de `+`, subtrair se tiver o sinal de `-` ou retornar "nenhuma das opções" se o sinal não for nenhum desses dois.

Escrevi da seguinte maneira:

```
var somaSubtracao;
function somaSubtracao(num1, num2) {
    if (somaSubtracao = "+") {
        return num1 + num2;
    } if (somaSubtracao === "-") {
        return num1 - num2;
    } else {
        return "nenhuma das opções";
    }
}
console.log(somaSubtracao);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que, salvo erro de digitação, sua intenção era comparar alguém a um valor mas na verdade você está atribuindo um valor a alguém    `if (somaSubtracao = "+")`

Sinal de igual atribui e dois sinais de igual compara
, existe ainda 3 sinais de igual `===` que significa estritamente igual (verifica conteúdo e tipo da variável).

Quando uma função recebe parâmetros, ela atribui os valores recebidos aos nomes de variável especificados nos parênteses da definição da função. Considere o seguinte segmento de script:

```js
function somaSubtracao(num1) {
  console.log(num1);
}
somaSubtracao(3);
```

Após a função ser definida, a próxima instrução chama essa mesma função, passando o numero 3. `somaSubtracao(3);` e a função vai atribuir esse valor a variável `num1` e realizar algo com ele.

**Na definição da sua função** você deveria esperar 3 paramentos, ou seja, dois números e um terceiro cujo o valor vai indicar o que se deve fazer com os números passados, soma ou subtração.

```
function somaSubtracao(num1, num2, somaSubtracao) {
```

Dessa forma faltou na função um terceiro parâmetro que seria a operação entre os outros dois parâmetros passados.

Feito isso chame a função e passe os 3 parâmetros que ela espera, dois números e um sinal que representa soma ou subtração

```
  somaSubtracao(3, 6, '+');
```

A estrutura condicional correta é:

```
if (condição 1) {
   faça isso
} else if (condição 2) {
   faça isso
} else {
  faça isso
}
```

**No seu caso seria**

```js
function somaSubtracao(num1, num2, somaSubtracao) {
    if (somaSubtracao == "+") {
        return num1 + num2;
    } else if (somaSubtracao == "-") {
        return num1 - num2;
    } else {
        return "nenhuma das opções";
    }
}

console.log(somaSubtracao(3, 6, '+'));
console.log(somaSubtracao(3, 6, '-')); 
console.log(somaSubtracao(3, 6));
```

**O que?** nome de função igual a nome de variável? Isso é resposta para outra pergunta :-)

Talvez possa gostar de estar estudando um pouco mais

```js
function somaSubtracao(num1, num2) {
let Accum=0;
( !isNaN(num1) && !isNaN(num2) ) ? Accum=(num1+num2) : Accum=("nenhuma das opções");
return Accum;
}

 console.log(somaSubtracao(3, 6));
 console.log(somaSubtracao(3, -6)); 
 console.log(somaSubtracao(-3, -6));
 console.log(somaSubtracao(3));
 console.log(somaSubtracao('x', 3));
```

isNaN - usado para verificar quando não é um número, então se você quer saber se é numérico pode usar `!isNaN`. o simbolo `!` é negação, portanto a negação de `não numérico` é `numérico`

A expressão `( !isNaN(num1) && !isNaN(num2) ) ? Accum=(num1+num2) : Accum=("nenhuma das opções");` é operador condicional ternário. Ele avalia expressões condicionais, de maneira parecida com o if, veja essa resposta  do [bfavaretto♦](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4907/como-funciona-este-if-else-com-e/4916#4916) sobre operador ternário.

Comment: Gostaria que descrevesse como se lê essa linha do código ainda não vi esse tipo: ( !isNaN(num1) && !isNaN(num2) ) ? Accum=(num1+num2) : Accum=("nenhuma das opções");     Foi perfeito seu comentário, esclareceu muito!

Comment: @MarcelinhaMCZ, editei a minha resposta e indiquei uma boa resposta sobre o assunto

Answer (score 1):

Basicamente faltou passar na função o tipo de operação e no momento da chamada do método passar qual operação a que deseja fazer, exemplo:

```js
function somaSubtracao(num1, num2, operacao) {
    if (operacao === "+") return num1 + num2;
    if (operacao === "-") return num1 - num2;
    return "nenhuma das opções";    
}

console.log(somaSubtracao(10, 20, '+'));
console.log(somaSubtracao(40, 20, '-'));
console.log(somaSubtracao(10, 20, ''));
```

Answer (score 0):

só complementando o comentário acima...

Note que você apenas declarou a função, mas ainda não a utilizou.

```js
function somaSubtracao(num1, num2, operacao) {
    if (operacao === "+") return num1 + num2;
    if (operacao === "-") return num1 - num2;
    return "nenhuma das opções";    
}

console.log(somaSubtracao(10, 20, '+'));
console.log(somaSubtracao(40, 20, '-'));
console.log(somaSubtracao(10, 20, ''));
```