# Como criar esse ternário que expressa mais que strings via console?

Tags: javascript

Estou criando desafios para mim mesmo para ter uma boa base de treino e memória de certos módulos e funções em JS. Eu aprendi sobre ternário faz uns dois dias, e desde então, estou tentando usar apenas ele para realizar as condições de if/else - que acho MUITO longas, e menos eficientes.

No HTML proposto, existe hum (1) botão que deve **'ligar'** e **'desligar'** o **Switch1**, com valor de 0 por padrão, em seguida, fiz um botão verificador para dar um retorno via console.log() sobre o estado dessa mesma variável (Switch1).

Como posso expressar o ato de 'ligar' e 'desligar' o switch usando **Operadores Ternários**? Podem me ajudar, por favor?

```html
    /* Criar uma variavel que alterne entre 'true' e 'false', e em seguida aplicar um Switch verificador para
        validar o estado atual da mesma */

        var button1 = 0;
        /* var button2 = 0; */

    function switch1() {
        (switch1 >= 1 ? (switch = 0 : switch =1));
    }    

    function verEstado() {
        switch (button1) {
            case 1 :
                console.log('Switch1 está ativo');
                break
            case 0 :
                console.log('Switch 1 está inativo!')
                break
        };
    };
```

[Um exemplo de como ficou, graficamente](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28wkK.png)

Comment: Veja se te ajuda: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4907/como-funciona-este-if-else-com-e

Answer (score -2):

Pelo o que entendi você quer transformar o switch da função ver estado em um ternário, se for isso...

```
    function verEstado() {
  button1?console.log("Está ativo"):console.log("Está inativo")
}
```

O primeiro console.log é para o valor verdadeiro, o segundo, para o falso. Uma coisa importante de se saber é que o valor de true é 1, o de false é 0, por causa dos números binários, e como nosso switch só nos retorna valores 0 e 1, só coloquei button1, pois se ele for 1 vai ser verdadeiro, pegando o "Está ativo, se for 0, será falso, pegando o está "inativo"

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta  no caso, a 'function switch1' que criei deveria verificar se o switch está ativo, se sim ele mudaria o valor para 0 (desligando-a) e vice-versa. Não sei bem como fazer, pois depois do '?' eu tento por um 'switch1 = 0 : switch1 = 1' mas ao invés de alternar os estados ele não faz nada  acho que empaquei nisso porquê depois que começo não consigo parar de pensar rsrs ` function switch1(button1) {
        switch1 >= 1 ?  0 : 1;
        /* return console.log('Switch alterado!') */
    };`

Comment: Tenta isso: 
function switch1() {
        switch1?switch1=0 : switch1=1;
    }

Comment: Cara, nem sei como agradecer  depois que você comentou sobre a atribuição (que era bem óbvia!) eu percebi que, na linha que postei e que estava usando, a variável desse botão era na verdade 'button1'. Depois da modificação, consegui fazer o botão alternar como um interruptor de luz, e depois realizar a verificação via log  MUITO OBRIGADO, vou dar continuidade no curso a partir de hoje

Answer (score -2):

Algo bom para se praticar é colocar o *button1* como parâmetro da função, assim você pode reutiliza-las quando quiser. Agora não vai fazer muita diferença, mas quando evoluir como programador vai.

Exemplo:

```
    function verEstado(btn) {
        btn?console.log("Está ativo"):console.log("Está inativo")
```

}

Ai na hora de chamar a função você faz o seguinte:

```
verEstado(button1)
```

Answer (score -2):

Depois de ajustado, acabei encontrando meu erro. Deixarei como resposta para caso existam outros iniciantes como eu

```js
var button1 = true;
       
    function switch1() {
        
        if (button1 == true) {
            button1 = false;
            console.log('Alterado para Falso')
        } else {
            button1 = true; 
            console.log('Alterado para Verdadeiro')
        };
        
        /* Antes estava verificando uma variavel inexistente ('switch1'), acabei me perdendo entre os termos
        mas enfim consegui reatribuir o valor de 'button1' conforme seu estado atual (true/false). Quase que como
        um interruptor de lâmpada, que era o desafio*/
        
    };    

    function verEstado() {
        switch (button1) {
            case true :
                console.log('Switch1 é Verdadeiro');
                break
            case false :
                console.log('Switch 1 é Falso')
                break
        };
    };
```

Comment: Dá pra ser mais simples: `function switch1() { button1 = ! button1; console.log('Alterado para', button1 ? 'Verdadeiro' : 'Falso'); }` e `function verEstado() { console.log('Switch1 é', button1 ? 'Verdadeiro' : 'Falso'); }`